# Toggle a string

Tags: code-golf, string

> The challenge involve simply toggling a string within another string.

### Explanation

If the **toggle string** is a substring of the **main string**, remove all instances of the **toggle string** from the **main string**; otherwise, append the **toggle string** at the end of the **main string**.

### Rules

- All string are composed of printable ASCII characters
- The function should take two parameters: the **main string** and the **toggle string**.
- The **main string** can be empty.
- The **toggle string** cannot be empty.
- The result should be a string, which can be empty.
- The shortest answer wins.

### Examples

```
function toggle(main_string, toggle_string){ ... }

toggle('this string has 6 words ', 'now') 
=> 'this string has 6 words now'

toggle('this string has 5 words now', ' now') 
=> 'this string has 5 words'
```

### Tests cases

```
'','a'          => 'a'
'a','a'         => ''

'b','a'         => 'ba'
'ab','a'        => 'b'

'aba','a'       => 'b'
'ababa', 'aba'  => 'ba'
```

Comment: And once it goes to the main namespace, you guys ask all sorts of questions

Comment: @KennyLau It was in the sandbox for all of 3 hours. The recommendation is 2 days.

Comment: The recommendation is actually [72 hours](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7296/42963). The main page has much more visibility than the Sandbox, so more comments are guaranteed here. That said, this isn't a *bad* challenge, just has a few rough edges.

Comment: So you replace all *non-overlapping* instances?

Comment: You can break quite a few solutions with the test-case: `'abc.', '.'`, since quite a lot of them use some sort of regex.

Comment: @Jakube Yes, I should limit this to letters and number I think.

Comment: No, I think allow nonalphanumerics: it's more challenging that way.

Comment: Is the order of the function parameters fixed (`main_string` as first and `toggle_string` as second parameter) or it is allowed to change the order?

Comment: Yes, but you can propose your solution anyway, just for the challenge :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œṣȮ⁸e⁹ẋ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZPhuaPIruKBuGXigbnhuos&input=&args=J3RoaXMgc3RyaW5nIGhhcyA2IHdvcmRzICc+J25vdyc)

#### How it works

```
œṣȮ⁸e⁹ẋ  Main link. Arguments: s (string), t (toggle string)

œṣ       Split s at occurrences of t.
  Ȯ      Print the result.
   ⁸e    Check if s occurs in the split s. Yields 1 (true) or 0 (false).
     ⁹ẋ  Repeat t that many times.
```

Answer (score 11):

## Java 8, <s>80</s> <s>70</s> <s>65</s> 34 bytes

```java
t->m->m==(m=m.replace(t,""))?m+t:m
```

Probably my shortest Java 'codegolf' so far.. xD
with some help from the comments.. ;)

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nY5BC4JAEIXv/orB00q6PyDTbt06eYwO42qxtrsuOgoS/nbb0IJuGgzMg3nvzVdhj1FtS1MVj0kobFs4ozRPD6AlJCmgcg7ekVT81hlBsjb8tIhDRo0093CVZ95pCgISmChKtZskYTrRvCmtQlEyCn0/CI56R3s9xZ6DsF2uHMTC0teyAO342Nx2uWLwRgXIhpZKzeuOuHUXUoYJjtaqgfnoBx/p2uMtftwayDd/@COxkir/DX1jozdOLw)

```java
t->m->                     // Method with two String parameters and String return-type
                           // (NOTE: Takes the toggle `t` and main `m` in reversed order)
  m==(m=m.replace(t,""))?  //  If `m` equals `m` with all `t`-substrings removed:
                           //  (And set `m` to `m` with all `t`-substrings removed)
   m+t                     //   Output this new `m` concatted with `t`
  :                        //  Else:
   m                       //   Output just this new `m`
```

Comment: You should be able to save quite a few by changing the `if` to a ternary. If nothing else, it'll get rid of the "extra" `return`.

Comment: @Geobits Ah, of course.. I was so enthusiastic that a single method had a 'low' byte count (in terms of java 'codegolfing') that I forgot one of the most obvious codegolfing for ifs and returns.. >.> Thanks, edited.

Comment: You can save a few more bytes by using a lambda instead of a regular function.

Comment: `return m=m.replace(t,"")?m+t:m;`

Comment: @KennyLau `m=m.replace(t,"")` isn't a boolean for the ternary if-operation.. :S And if you ment `m==m.replace...` instead, then the output is incorrect.

Comment: `m==(m=m.replace...`

Comment: @KennyLau Nice trick, thanks. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 8):

## MATL, 11 bytes

```
yyXf?''YX}h
```

[Try it Online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXlYZj8nJ1lYfWg&input=J2FiYWJhJwonYWJhJw)

[All test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YGlpeXlYZj8nJ1lYfWhdRFRd&input=JycKJ2EnCidhJwonYScKJ2InCidhJwonYWInCidhJwonYWJhJwonYScKJ2FiYWJhJwonYWJhJw)

**Explanation**

```
            % Implicitly grab the main string
            % Implicitly grab the toggle string
y           % Copy the main string
y           % Copy the toggle string
Xf          % Check to see if the toggle string is present in the main string
?           % If so
    ''YX    % Replace with an empty string
}           % else
    h       % Horizontally concatenate the two strings
            % Implicit end of if...else
            % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 38 bytes

```
lambda s,t:(s+t,s.replace(t,""))[t in s]
```

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
(s,t,u=s.split(t).join``)=>u==s?s+t:u
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 14 bytes

```
DX{iIXRk:)i!IJ
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=DX%7BiIXRk%3A%29i%21IJ&input=%5B%22this+string+has+5+words+now%22%2C%22now%22%5D)

Given that Pyke has no `else` structure, I think this is pretty reasonable score

Explanation:

```
D              -    Duplicate input
 X             -   a,b = ^
  {            -  a in b
   i           - i = ^
    I          - if i:
     XRk:      -  a = b.replace(a,"")
         i!I   - if not i:
            J  -  a = "".join(input)
               - print a
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 9

```
q~:B/2Be]
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7E%3AB%2F2Be%5D&input=%22code%20golf%22%20%22o%22) Thanks jimmy23013 for chopping off 1 byte :)

**Explanation:**

```
q~     read and evaluate the input (given as 2 quoted strings)
:B     store the toggle string in B
/      split the main string by the toggle string
2Be]   pad the array of pieces to the right with B, up to length 2 (if shorter)
```

Comment: 9 bytes: `q~:B/2Be]`.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
?/Qz:Qzk+z
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%2FQz%3AQzk%2Bz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22a%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22b%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22ab%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22aba%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22ababa%22%0Aaba%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

Input format: first string in quotes, second string without quotes.

#### This is also 10 bytes:

```
?tJcQzsJ+z
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3FtJcQzsJ%2Bz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22a%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22b%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22ab%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22aba%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22ababa%22%0Aaba%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

#### This is 11 bytes:

```
pscQz*!}zQz
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=pscQz*!%7DzQz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22a%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22b%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22ab%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22aba%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22ababa%22%0Aaba%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

#### Previous 13-byte solution:

```
?:IQzk+Qz:Qzk
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%3AIQzk%2BQz%3AQzk&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22a%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22b%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22ab%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22aba%22%0Aa%0A%0A%22ababa%22%0Aaba%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

Comment: Also 11 bytes: `?}zQ:Qzk+Qz`

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ECMAScript 6): 47 bytes

```
(a,b)=>(c=a.replace(RegExp(b,'g'),''))!=a?c:a+b
```

Comment: This can fail if the toggle string contains special characters. For example, `("a", ".")` returns `""` instead of `"a."`.

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), <s>38</s> 31 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
(.+)(?=.*¶\1$)
·
1>`·|¶.+

T`·¶
```

The trailing linefeed is significant. Input format is both strings separated with a linefeed.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAooLispKD89Lio7XDEkKQohCjE-YCF8Oy4rCgpUYCE7&input=dGhpcyBzdHJpbmcgaGFzIDYgd29yZHMgO25vdwp0aGlzIHN0cmluZyBoYXMgNSB3b3JkcyBub3c7IG5vdwo7YQphO2EKYjthCmFiO2EKYWJhO2EKYWJhYmE7YWJhCmFiYWJhYmFiYTthYmE) The first line allows running several test cases at once (for the test suite, use `;` to separate the strings and linefeeds to separate test cases; the first line takes care of the conversion).

#### Explanation

```
(.+)(?=.*¶\1$)
·
```

In this first step we replace all occurrences of the toggle string in the main string with `·`. We need to insert these markers so that we can determine afterwards if any substitution happened.

```
1>`·|¶.+
```

This is another substitution which removes a `·` marker, or the second line (including the separating linefeed). However, the `1>` is a limit which means that only matches *after* the first are considered. Hence, if the toggle string did not occur in the main string, we won't have inserted any `·`, so the second line will be the first match and won't be removed. Otherwise, we remove the second line along with all but the first marker.

```
T`·¶
```

While this uses a transliteration stage, it's also used simply for removing characters. In particular, we move both `·` and linefeeds. We need the first one, in case there was a match (because then the first `·` will have been left behind by the previous stage) and we need the second one in case there wasn't a match (to join the two lines together and thereby append the toggle string to the main string).

Answer (score 2):

## Python (3.4): <s>55</s> <s>54</s> <s>47</s> 44 Bytes

```
lambda m,t:m.replace(t,'')if t in m else m+t
```

Testing:

```
toggle=lambda m,t:m.replace(t,'')if t in m else m+t
print('', 'a', toggle('','a'))
print('a', 'a', toggle('a','a'))
print('b', 'a', toggle('b','a'))
print('ab', 'a', toggle('ab','a'))
print('aba', 'a', toggle('aba','a'))
print('ababa', 'aba', toggle('ababa','aba'))
```

The Test output

```
 a a
a a
b a ba
ab a b
aba a b
ababa aba ba
```

<s>Using a def would be longer because you have to use a return statement, if it were possible without return it would save 2 Bytes</s>
Since explicit declaration of the function is not needed (sorry I didn't know that) 7 Bytes were saved.

Comment: Nice answer! For our rules, you don't need a name for the function. So you can remove the `toggle=`.

Comment: I just realized, my Test won't work if I don't name the function, but with the `toggle=` the Tests work

Comment: yes, the `toggle` is needed to test it. But you only need to _count_ from `lambda m,t:` on.

Comment: You can change `m+''+t` to `m+t` to save 3 bytes, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You're right, I started with `m+' '+t` to enter a space between them, but after reading the description again I deleted the whitespace but not the '' and the +

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, <strike>72</strike> 70 bytes

```
def x(m:String,s:String)={val r=m.replaceAll(s,"");if(r==m)m+s else r}
```

Online interpreter: [www.tryscala.com](http://www.tryscala.com)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! I don't know Scala, but I think you can remove the spaces around `if(r==m)`.

Comment: Yeah you are right

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 63

```
string F(string s,string t)=>s.Contains(t)?s.Replace(t,""):s+t;
```

Better than Java :)

Test code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(F("", "a"));
    Console.WriteLine(F("a", "a"));
    Console.WriteLine(F("b", "a"));
    Console.WriteLine(F("ab", "a"));
    Console.WriteLine(F("aba", "a"));
    Console.WriteLine(F("ababa", "aba"));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
a

ba
b
b
ba
```

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 12 bytes

```
?=iγρiIE+iIγ
```

Or, if we must include regex-sensitive chars:

```
?=iγρiLeIE+iIγ
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Pz1pzrPPgWlMZUlFK2lJzrM&input=SGVsbG8sIHBlcnNvbiEKCiwgcGVyc29uIQ)

### Explanation

```
?=iγρiIE+iIγ    if(i === (γ = i.replace(I, E))) alert(i + I); else alert(γ);
  i                i
 =                   ===
    ρ                          .replace( ,  )
     iI                       i         I 
       E                                   E
   γ                     (γ =                )
?               if(                           )
        +iI                                     alert(i + I);
                                                              else
           γ                                                       alert(γ);
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 Bytes

```
(m,t)=>(w=m.split(t).join``)==m?m+t:w
```

Slightly shorter than @nobe4 's answer by taking advantage of split and join

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 70 bytes

Pretty straight forward.

```rkt
(λ(s t)((if(string-contains? s t)string-replace string-append)s t""))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 66 bytes

```sql
SELECT DECODE(:1,s,s||:2,s)FROM(SELECT REPLACE(:1,:2)s FROM DUAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>35</s> <s>37</s> 28 bytes

```ruby
->m,t{m[t]?m.gsub(t,''):m+t}
```

Hooray for string interpolation! It even works in regexes. The rest is simple: if the string in `t` matches to `m`, replace `t` with `''`, else return `m+t`.

**Edit:** Fixed a bug.

**Edit:** I applied Kevin Lau's suggestion, but it appears that I have reached the same algorithm as the one used in [Luis Masuelli's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80303/47581).

Comment: This can fail if the toggle string contains special characters. For example, `("a", ".")` returns `"a"` instead of `"a."`.

Comment: `m[t]` is much shorter than `m.include?(t)` and still checks for inclusion within strings.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```julia
s|t=(r=replace(s,t,""))t^(s==r)
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=c3x0PShyPXJlcGxhY2Uocyx0LCIiKSl0XihzPT1yKQoKcHJpbnRsbigidGhpcyBzdHJpbmcgaGFzIDYgd29yZHMgInwibm93IikKcHJpbnRsbigidGhpcyBzdHJpbmcgaGFzIDUgd29yZHMgbm93InwiIG5vdyIpCnByaW50bG4oIiJ8ImEiKQpwcmludGxuKCJhInwiYSIpCnByaW50bG4oImIifCJhIikKcHJpbnRsbigiYWIifCJhIikKcHJpbnRsbigiYWJhInwiYSIpCnByaW50bG4oImFiYWJhInwiYWJhIik&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>33 bytes</s> <s>27 bytes (28 if using global subtitution)</s> definitely 28 bytes

```
->u,v{u[v]?u.gsub(v,''):u+v}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>37</s> 30 bytes

```perl
{$_=shift;s/\Q@_//g?$_:"$_@_"}
```

Regular expressions inside the toggle string are not evaluate because of the quoting with `\Q`...`\E`.

`sub F` and `\E` are  removed  according to the [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80243/toggle-a-string/80306?noredirect=1#comment197404_80306) by  msh210.

It is not entirely free of side effects because of setting `$_`. Using a local variable will cost six additional bytes:

```perl
{my$a=shift;$a=~s/\Q@_//g?$a:"$a@_"}
```

On the other hand, with switched input parameters two bytes can be saved by using `pop` instead of `shift` (28 bytes):

```perl
{$_=pop;s/\Q@_//g?$_:"$_@_"}
```

Test file:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

sub F{$_=shift;s/\Q@_//g?$_:"$_@_"}

sub test ($$$) {
  my ($m, $t, $r) = @_;
  my $result = F($m, $t);
  print "F('$m', '$t') -> '$result' ",
    ($result eq $r ? '=OK=' : '<ERROR>'), " '$r'\n";
}
test '', 'a', 'a';
test 'a', 'a', '';
test 'b', 'a', 'ba';
test 'ab', 'a', 'b';
test 'aba', 'a', 'b';
test 'ababa', 'aba', 'ba';
test 'ababa', 'a*', 'ababaa*';
test 'foobar', '.', 'foobar.';
__END__
```

Test result:

```perl
F('', 'a') -> 'a' =OK= 'a'
F('a', 'a') -> '' =OK= ''
F('b', 'a') -> 'ba' =OK= 'ba'
F('ab', 'a') -> 'b' =OK= 'b'
F('aba', 'a') -> 'b' =OK= 'b'
F('ababa', 'aba') -> 'ba' =OK= 'ba'
F('ababa', 'a*') -> 'ababaa*' =OK= 'ababaa*'
F('foobar', '.') -> 'foobar.' =OK= 'foobar.'
```

Comment: perlsub says "The signature is part of a subroutine's body. Normally the body of a subroutine is simply a braced block of code." Thus, you can omit `sub F` from your byte count. Also, you should be able to use `pop` instead of `shift` (by reversing the order of the inputs, natch), saving two bytes. (Untested.) Finally, you should be able to omit the `\E`, saving two more bytes. (Also untested.)

Comment: @msh210 Thanks, your tips saved seven bytes. I do not see, how `pop` instead of `shift` can help, because `$_` should be the first argument to avoid `$_[1]=~s/.../`. The order of input arguments is fixed by the question AFAIK.

Comment: The order of input arguments is not fixed by the question afaict.

Answer (score 1):

## C# (58 bytes)

`string F(string s,string t)=>s==(s=s.Replace(t,""))?s+t:s;`

It uses an inline assignment to shave a few bytes off

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Great first post! I don't use C# much, but can't you do `var s,t` or `var s,var t` instead of `string`?

Comment: Thanks! Sadly `var` can only be used in places where the type is known at compile time, so it can't be used in method signatures. You could use `dynamic`, but it's 1 character longer that `string`

Comment: What about `var F(string s, string t`? That can be inferred...

Answer (score 1):

## bash + sed, 28 bytes

```
sed "s/$2//g;t;s/$/$2/"<<<$1
```

The script lives in a toggle-string.bash file, which we call with `bash toggle-string.bash mainstring togglestring`.

`s/$2//g` removes the toggle string from the main string

`t` jumps to the end if the previous substitution was successful (ie. the main string contained the toggle string)

`/$/$2/` adds the toggle string at the end (`$`), if we didn't jump to the end

bash is required for the herestring

Comment: This won't work if the toggle string contains special characters.

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 47 bytes

```
param($a,$b)(($c=$a-replace$b),"$a$b")[$c-eq$a]
```

Takes input `$a,$b` and then uses a pseudo-ternary `(... , ...)[...]` statement to perform an if/else. The inner parts are evaluated first to form an array of two elements. The 0th is `$a` with all occurrences of `$b` `-replace`d with nothing, which is stored into `$c`. The 1st is just a string concatenation of `$a` and `$b`.

If `$c` is `-eq`ual to `$a`, meaning that `$b` wasn't found, that's Boolean `$true` or `1`, and so the 1st element of the array (the concatenation) is chosen. Else, it's Boolean `$false`, so we output `$c`, the 0th element.

Note that `-replace` is greedy, so it will replace from the left first, meaning the `ababa / aba` test case will properly return `ba`.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 65 bytes

```
BinaryOperator<String>l=(m,t)->m.contains(t)?m.replace(t,""):m+t;
```

The same logic as the Java 7 solution, written with a lambda.

[Try it here](http://ideone.com/v5Uh0G)

Answer (score 0):

**TSQL, <strike>143</strike> <strike>129</strike> 121 Bytes**

```
DECLARE @1 VARCHAR(10)='',@2 VARCHAR(10)='a'SELECT CASE WHEN @1 LIKE'%'+@2+'%'THEN REPLACE(@1,@2,'')ELSE CONCAT(@1,@2)END
```

Readable:

```
   DECLARE @1 VARCHAR(10) = ''
    , @2 VARCHAR(10) = 'a'

SELECT CASE WHEN @1 LIKE '%' + @2 + '%'
            THEN REPLACE(@1, @2, '')
            ELSE CONCAT (@1, @2)
            END
```

<kbd>**[`Live Demo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/488831)**</kbd>

**114 Bytes** with strictly 1 character input

```
DECLARE @1 CHAR(1) = 'a'
    , @2 CHAR(1) = '.'

SELECT CASE WHEN @1 LIKE '%' + @2 + '%'
            THEN REPLACE(@1, @2, '')
            ELSE CONCAT (@1, @2) END
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 45 bytes

```
If[StringContainsQ@##,StringDelete@##,#<>#2]&
```

Anonymous function that takes the main string and the toggle string (in that order) and returns the result. Explanation:

```
                                            &  Anonymous function returning...

If[StringContainsQ@##,               ,     ]    if its first argument contains
                                                its second argument, then...
                      StringDelete@##            its first argument with its
                                                 second argument removed, else...
                                      #<>#2      its second argument appended to
                                                 its first argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

## TSQL(Sqlserver 2012), 49 bytes

```
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(10) = 'hello',@x VARCHAR(10) = 'o'

PRINT IIF(@ LIKE'%'+@x+'%',REPLACE(@,@x,''),@+@x)
```

[Try it online!](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/488976/toggle-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

## k (23 bytes)

```
{$[#x ss y;,/y\:x;x,y]}
```

Examples:

```
k){$[#x ss y;,/y\:x;x,y]}["aba";"a"]
,"b"
k){$[#x ss y;,/y\:x;x,y]}["this string has 6 words ";"now"]
"this string has 6 words now"
k){$[#x ss y;,/y\:x;x,y]}["this string has 5 words now";"now"]
"this string has 5 words "
k){$[#x ss y;,/y\:x;x,y]}["ababa";"ba"]
,"a"
k){$[#x ss y;,/y\:x;x,y]}["";"a"]
,"a"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin, 61 Bytes

```
{m:String,t:String->var n=m.replace(t,"");if(m==n)m+t else n}
```

This is would be shorter if assignment was an expression in Kotlin,and parameters were mutable,and there was a ternary conditional operator, sadly this isn't the case :(

[Try it Online!](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/imoa5gjbnol7adr9n38tqja56a/q2a6ai0gv7gqjialn6rkrpo2bg)

#### UnGolfed

```
fun t(m:String, t:String):String{
    var n=m.replace(t, "")
    return if(m==n)m+t else n
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 84 bytes

```
fn toggle(a:&str,b:&str)->String{let mut r=a.replace(b,"");if&r==a{r.push_str(b)}r}
```

Try it on [play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b7d15666f223a1f7f06ce30aea9d6554&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 65

```
function f($s,$v){return($m=str_replace($v,'',$s))==$s?$s.$v:$m;}
```

Inspired from Kevin Cruijssen's java example.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 73 chars

`<?$s=$argv[1];$t=$argv[2];echo!strpos($s,$t)?$s.$t:str_replace($t,'',$s);`

Longer than [the other php answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80441/43587), but uninspired and fully working as a standalone in the console.