# Weapons of Math Instruction

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic, array

Last time when I tried to come up with something easy that wasn't a duplicate, it ended up being way too hard.. So hopefully this time it's indeed something newcomers can try as well.

**Input:**

An array/list with integers/decimals. (Or a string representing an array with integers/decimals.)

**Output:**

Loop through the numbers and apply the following five mathematical operands in this order:

- Addition (`+`);
- Subtraction (`−`);
- Multiplication (`*` or `×` or `·`);
- *Real / Calculator* Division (`/` or `÷`);
- Exponentiation (`^` or `**`).

(NOTE: The symbols between parenthesis are just added as clarification. If your programming language uses a completely different symbol for the mathematical operation than the examples, then that is of course completely acceptable.)

Keep continuing until you've reached the end of the list, and then give the result of the sum.

**Challenge rules:**

- Exponentiation by 0 (`n ^ 0`) should result in 1 (this also applies to `0 ^ 0 = 1`).
- There are no test cases for division by 0 (`n / 0`), so you don't have to worry about that edge-case.
- If the array contains just a single number, we return that as the result.

**General rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.

**Test cases:**

```
[1,2,3,4,5] -> 0
-> 1 + 2 = 3
  -> 3 - 3 = 0
    -> 0 * 4 = 0
      -> 0 / 5 = 0 

[5,12,23,2,4,4,2,6,7] -> 539
-> 5 + 12 = 17
  -> 17 - 23 = -6
    -> -6 * 2 = -12
      -> -12 / 4 = -3
        -> -3 ^ 4 = 81
          -> 81 + 2 = 83
            -> 83 - 6 = 77
              -> 77 * 7 -> 539

[-8,50,3,3,-123,4,17,99,13] -> -1055.356...
-> -8 + 50 = 42
  -> 42 - 3 = 39
    -> 39 * 3 = 117
      -> 117 / -123 = -0.9512...
        -> -0.9512... ^ 4 = 0.818...
          -> 0.818... + 17 = 17.818...
            -> 17.818... - 99 -> -81.181...
              -> -81.181... * 13 = -1055.356...

[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] -> 256
-> 2 + 2 = 4
  -> 4 - 2 = 2
    -> 2 * 2 = 4
      -> 4 / 2 = 2
        -> 2 ^ 2 = 4
          -> 4 + 2 = 6
            -> 6 - 2 = 4
              -> 4 * 2 = 8
                -> 8 / 2 = 4
                  -> 4 ^ 2 = 16
                    -> 16 + 2 = 18
                      -> 18 - 2 = 16
                        -> 16 * 2 = 32
                          -> 32 / 2 = 16
                            -> 16 ^ 2 = 256

[1,0,1,0,1,0] -> 1
-> 1 + 0 = 1
  -> 1 - 1 = 0
    -> 0 * 0 = 0
      -> 0 / 1 = 0
        -> 0 ^ 0 = 1

[-9,-8,-1] -> -16
  -> -9 + -8 = -17
    -> -17 - -1 = -16

[0,-3] -> -3
  -> 0 + -3 = -3

[-99] -> -99
```

Comment: Not integer division?

Comment: @LeakyNun No. Perhaps I should change the input to a list with decimals instead of integers due to division (and test case 3)?

Comment: Was this in the sandbox?

Comment: @Bálint Yes, [since Friday morning (CET)](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/9340#9340) (it's deleted now, but those without enough rep can still view it). And I received some good feedback from _TimmyD_ and _flawr_ that has improved the challenge a lot. (PS: Since I get this question every time I post a challenge, should I add a link to the deleted Sandbox & datetime next time?)

Comment: No need, just answer this question every time you post a challenge. :)

Comment: For clarification, does `0^0 = 1`? From the description, it seems so, but you might want to make it explicit just in case.

Comment: @Mego Yes, `0^0 = 1`. A.f.a.i.k., `n ^ 0` is always `1` regardless of `n` in math (or are there different mathematical rules here, since you aren't the first to ask?). It also has the answer `1` in the 5th test case for `0 ^ 0`. But I'll add it at the top as well to clarify it explicitly.

Comment: In math, there are two conflicting "rules": `n ^ 0 = 1`, but `0 ^ n = 0`. The conflict is resolved by setting `n != 0` for both of the rules, but then it leaves `0 ^ 0` undefined. However, there are a lot of things that fall into place nicely in mathematics if `0 ^ 0` is defined to be `1`. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) for some details.

Comment: If I return infinity instead of a divide by zero error, is thst okay?

Comment: @Bálint The rules state that there will never be a valid input with a division by zero. You don't have to worry about that edge case.

Comment: @Mego He said there's no testcase for it, but should normally ouput an error

Comment: @Bálint The wording could be a bit clearer, but that is the interpretation I and the other posters have been going off of, since that was the suggestion in the Sandbox that led to the rule being added.

Comment: @Bálint _@Mego_ is indeed right, you don't have to worry about divide by 0 cases / errors. I've chanegd the wording to clarify it a bit.

Comment: `*` is APL's symbol for exponentiation. Is this acceptable if one of the other two multiplication symbols is used?

Comment: @Adám Yes, the symbols were just added as clarification of the mathematical operations in the sense of: _pictures (or symbols) say more than thousand words_. It's completely fine if your language uses even none of the symbols, as long as they imply and are executed as their counterpart mathematical operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“+_×÷*”ṁṖ⁸żFV
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcK1_Dl8O3KuKAneG5geG5luKBuMW8RlY&input=&args=Wy04LDUwLDMsMywtMTIzLDQsMTcsOTksMTNd) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcK1_Dl8O3KuKAneG5geG5luKBuMW8RlYKw4figqw&input=&args=WzEsMiwzLDQsNV0sIFs1LDEyLDIzLDIsNCw0LDIsNiw3XSwgWy04LDUwLDMsMywtMTIzLDQsMTcsOTksMTNdLCBbMiwyLDIsMiwyLDIsMiwyLDIsMiwyLDIsMiwyLDIsMl0sIFsxLDAsMSwwLDEsMF0sIFstOSwtOCwtMV0sIFswLC0zXSwgWy05OV0).

#### How it works

```
“+_×÷*”ṁṖ⁸żFV  Main link. Argument: A (list of integers)

“+_×÷*”        Yield the list of operations as a string.
        Ṗ      Yield A popped, i.e., with its last element removed.
       ṁ       Mold; reshape the string as popped A.
               This repeats the characters of the string until it contains
               length(A)-1 characters.
         ⁸ż    Zipwith; pairs the integers of A with the corresponding characters.
           F   Flatten the result.
            V  Eval the resulting Jelly code.
               Jelly always evaluates left-to-right (with blatant disregard towards
               the order of operations), so this returns the desired result.
```

Comment: Nice, that's 8 lower byte-count than [_Pyke_](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82778/52210), which was currently in the lead.

Comment: Nobody outgolfs Dennis. Never.

Comment: Just a question: does it really count as 13 _bytes_ with all those non-ascii characters?

Comment: @XavierDury Yes. The **bytes** link in the header leads to Jelly's very own code page, which encodes the 256 characters Jelly understands as a single byte each.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you for the precision!

Answer (score 19):

## Javascript ES7 49 bytes

```
a=>a.reduce((c,d,e)=>[c**d,c+d,c-d,c*d,c/d][e%5])
```

Saved 9 bytes thanks to Dom Hastings, saved another 6 thanks to Leaky Nun

Uses the new exponentiation operator.

Comment: @LeakyNun won't that just produce `Infinity`, not an error?

Comment: Try using eval it might be shorter

Comment: @Upgoat It used eval first, then Leaky Nun showed me, that it is better, to do it like this

Comment: @Bálint you, like, using so many, commas?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Non-native speaker. Bálint often does that. English grammar is silly at the best of times.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ My language puts a comma pretty much everywhere, whether it be the end of a logical block or pretty much before every conjunction. I can't seem to drop this.

Answer (score 11):

## Haskell, <s>76</s> <s>65</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

Thanks to @Damien for removing another two bytes=)

```
f(u:v)=foldl(\x(f,y)->f x y)u(zip(v>>[(+),(-),(*),(/),(**)])v)
```

This uses the `>>` which here just appends the list `[(+),...]` to itself `length v` times. The rest still works still the same as the old versions.

Old versions:

These solutions make use of the infinite lists, as `cycle[...]` just repeats the given list infinitely. Then it basically gets `zip`ed with the list of numbers, and we just `fold` (*reduce* in other languages) the zipped list via a lambda, that applies the operators to the accumulator/current list element.

```
f(u:v)=foldl(\x(f,y)->f x y)u(zip(cycle[(+),(-),(*),(/),(**)])v)

f(u:v)=foldl(\x(y,f)->f x y)u(zip v(cycle[(+),(-),(*),(/),(**)]))

f l=foldl(\x(y,f)->f x y)(head l)(zip(drop 1l)(cycle[(+),(-),(*),(/),(**)]))
```

Comment: you can replace cycle by: v>>

Comment: @Damien Thank you very much!

Comment: Hm, `foldl(&)u$zipWith(&)v(flip<$>v>>[…])`?

Comment: @Bergi I honestly cannot read what this is doing anymore=) Anyway, we need an `import` for `&`, so that would be longer again, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @flawr: Actually my idea was quite the same as what [Lazersmoke posted as an answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82827/7588), I just hadn't read it. I got to it when trying to simplify that lamda of yours with something like `uncurry`. Didn't work out, but I noticed you should be able to save another byte by using `$` instead of parenthesis.

Answer (score 8):

### Pyke, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
lt5L%"+-*/^"L@\RJQ_XE
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=lt5L%25%22%2B-%2a%2F%5E%22L%40%5CRJQ_XE&input=%5B-8%2C50%2C3%2C3%2C-123%2C4%2C17%2C99%2C13%5D)

```
lt5L%                 -    map(len(input)-1, %5)
     "+-*/^"L@        -   map(^, "+-*/^"[<])
              \RJ     -  "R".join(^)
                    E - pyke_eval(^, V)
                 Q_X  -  splat(reversed(input))
```

Answer (score 7):

## TSQL <s>116</s> <s>115</s> 88 bytes

Thanks to Ross Presser suggestion I was able to golf this down to 88 characters

```sql
-- In Try-it code, this must be DECLARE @y TABLE 
CREATE TABLE T(a real, i int identity)
INSERT T values(5),(12),(23),(2),(4),(4),(2),(6),(7)

DECLARE @ REAL SELECT @=CHOOSE(i%5+1,@/a,ISNULL(POWER(@,a),a),@+a,@-a,@*a)FROM T
PRINT @
```

[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1064531/weapons-of-math-instruction)

Comment: 1 less byte: require the input table to be named T instead of @y. The PL/SQL solution had this, so why not TSQL.

Comment: @RossPresser yes of course. how did I miss that. It is not possible in the test link, no permissions to create tables, and it will only run correctly the first time on a database. But what does that matter when a character can be golfed. Thanks for your hint, your improvement has been added

Comment: Golfed out another 12 bytes: use CHOOSE instead of nested IIF, leaving one IIF for the i=1 case. With your permission, I will edit the answer.

Comment: answer edited. Here's the try-it link -- I'm anonymous so it has no name after it: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/499612

Comment: @RossPresser I didn't know CHOOSE. included your suggestion and golfed it a bit further

Comment: Nice!  88 bytes is halfway respectable for a golf! :)

Comment: I wonder if, as the number of rows in T increases without limit, the fact that the SELECT doesn't have an ORDER BY clause might bite us. If the optimizer picks a different order then the evaluation will be wrong.

Comment: @RossPresser this is not the correct way of doing it. There is an upper limit, but it is pretty high and will not be affected as long as the number of rows is low. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365024/create-string-of-month-year-in-order-by-date/33368354#33368354) is an example how to use XML-PATH which is the correct method

Comment: I'm interested - why SEDE? :3 I thought it was specifically for Stack Exchange data queries... :P

Comment: @user48538 you are right, seeding isn't necessary, I can just change the order of the processing

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, 61 Bytes

```
foldl(flip id)0.zipWith flip((+):cycle[(+),(-),(*),(/),(**)])
```

Creates a series of transformations in a list, as in [add 1, add 2, subtract 3, ...], starting with 2 additions because we start with 0 in the fold. Next, we do what I call the List Application Fold, or foldl (flip id), which applies a list of homomorphisms in series. This starts with zero, adds the initial value, then does all of the above computed transformations to get a final result.

Note that (flip id) is the same as (\x y->y x), just shorter.

Sample usage:

```
f = foldl(flip id)0.zipWith flip((+):cycle[(+),(-),(*),(/),(**)])
f [1,2,3,4,5] -- Is 0.0
```

Comment: Instead of `flip id`, you could simply use [`&`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-). Or `flip($)`. Wow, I never realised `($) = id`

Comment: @Bergi: `&` is defined in `Data.Function`, so you need the `import`, too. Maybe some online interpreter imports it by default, but then you need to specify which one you use.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
.v+>tlQ*lQ"^c*-+":jdQ\-\_
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.v%2B%3EtlQ%2alQ%22%5Ec%2a-%2B%22%3AjdQ%5C-%5C_&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A%5B5%2C12%2C23%2C2%2C4%2C4%2C2%2C6%2C7%5D%0A%5B-8%2C50%2C3%2C3%2C-123%2C4%2C17%2C99%2C13%5D%0A%5B2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%0A%5B-9%2C-8%2C-1%5D%0A%5B0%2C-3%5D%0A%5B-99%5D&debug=0)

Pyth uses prefix notation: `1+2` is written as `+1 2` (space needed to separate numbers).

Therefore, for the first testcase, the expression would be `(((1+2)-3)*4)/5`, which in prefix notation, would be written as `/*-+ 1 2 3 4 5`.

In Pyth, float division is `c` instead of `/`, so it becomes `c*-+ 1 2 3 4 5`.

Also, in Pyth, `-100` is written as `_100` instead.

Therefore, for the third test case, which is `((((((((-8+50)-3)*3)/-123)^4)+17)-99)*13)`, it becomes: `*-+^c*-+ _8 50 3 3 _123 4 17 99 13`.

```
.v+>tlQ*lQ"^c*-+":jdQ\-\_
                  jdQ       Join input by space.
                 :   \-\_   Replace "-" with "_".
   >tlQ*lQ"^c*-+"           Generate the string "...^c*-+" of suitable length.
  +                         Join the two strings above.
.v                          Evaluate as a Pyth expression.
```

### History

- 33 bytes: [`v:P+*lQ\(ssV+R\)Q*"+-*/p"lQ\p"**"`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/82774/1)
- 27 bytes: [`.vs+_XUtQUQ"+-*c^"m:+;d\-\_`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/82774/2)
- 26 bytes: [`.vs+_XUtQUQ"+-*c^":jdQ\-\_`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/82774/4)

Comment: You're fast! Seems like I succeeded in making an easier challenge. Or you're just THAT good. ;)

Comment: Because [it's similar to this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82717/turn-an-array-into-a-math-problem).

Comment: [24 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.vs%2B%40L%22%2B-%2ac%5E%22_UtQXjdQ%22-_&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A%5B5%2C12%2C23%2C2%2C4%2C4%2C2%2C6%2C7%5D%0A%5B-8%2C50%2C3%2C3%2C-123%2C4%2C17%2C99%2C13%5D%0A%5B2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%0A%5B-9%2C-8%2C-1%5D%0A%5B0%2C-3%5D%0A%5B-99%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 6):

### Actually, 23 bytes

```
;l"+-*/ⁿ"*@R':j':+'?o+ƒ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O2wiKy0qL-KBvyIqQFInOmonOisnP28rxpI&input=MSwyLDMsNCw1)

Actually uses postfix notation for mathematics, and operators that only ever take two arguments (such as the operators for addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponentiation) do nothing when there is only one element on the stack. Thus, turning the input into Actually code is as simple as reversing the input, formatting it as numerics, and appending the operations. Then, the resultant code can be executed, giving the desired output.

### Explanation:

```
;l"+-*/ⁿ"*@R':j':+'?o+ƒ
;l"+-*/ⁿ"*               repeat the operations a number of times equal to the length of the input
                            (since extraneous operations will be NOPs, there's no harm in overshooting)
          @R             reverse the input
            ':j          join on ":" (make a string, inserting ":" between every pair of elements in the list)
               ':+       prepend a ":" (for the first numeric literal)
                  '?o    append a "?"
                           (this keeps the poor numeric parsing from trying to gobble up the first + as part of the numeric literal, since ? isn't interpreted as part of the literal, and is a NOP)
                     +   append the operations string
                      ƒ  cast as a function and call it
```

Example of translated code for input `1,2,3,4,5`:

```
:5:4:3:2:1?+-*/ⁿ+-*/ⁿ+-*/ⁿ+-*/ⁿ+-*/ⁿ
```

Comment: Love the way the name of the language merges with the byte count

Comment: `s/Actually uses postfix notation/Actually actually uses postfix notation/`

Answer (score 6):

## Julia, <s>53</s> 50 bytes

```julia
!x=(i=0;foldl((a,b)->(+,-,*,/,^)[i=i%5+1](a,b),x))
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IXg9KGk9MDtmb2xkbCgoYSxiKS0-KCssLSwqLC8sXilbaT1pJTUrMV0oYSxiKSx4KSkKCmZvciB4IGluIChbMSwyLDMsNCw1XSwgWzUsMTIsMjMsMiw0LDQsMiw2LDddLCBbLTgsNTAsMywzLC0xMjMsNCwxNyw5OSwxM10sIFsyLDIsMiwyLDIsMiwyLDIsMiwyLDIsMiwyLDIsMiwyXSwgWzEsMCwxLDAsMSwwXSwgWy05LC04LC0xXSwgWzAsLTNdLCBbLTk5XSkKICAgIEBwcmludGYoIiUtMzNzIC0-ICVnXG4iLHgsIXgpCmVuZA&input=)

Answer (score 5):

## J, 40 bytes

```
^~`(%~)`*`(-~)`+/@(|.@,7#:~#&2)(5-5|4+#)
```

Finds the number of values needed to use a multiple of 5 operators, than pads with the identity values of those operators. In order, `+` is 0, `-` is 0, `*` is 1, `%` is 1, and `^` is 1, which can be a bit value `00111`, or 7 in base 10. Then operates on that list while cycling through operators.

### Usage

```
   f =: ^~`(%~)`*`(-~)`+/@(|.@,7#:~#&2)(5-5|4+#)
   f 1 2 3 4 5
0
   f 5 12 23 2 4 4 2 6 7
539
   f _8 50 3 3 _123 4 17 99 13
_1055.36
   f 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
256
   f 1 0 1 0 1 0
1
   f _9 _8 _1
_16
   f 0 _3
_3
   f _99
_99
```

### Explanation

```
^~`(%~)`*`(-~)`+/@(|.@,7#:~#&2)(5-5|4+#) Input: A
                                      #  Get length of A
                                    4+   Add four to it
                                  5|     Take it mod 5
                                5-       Find 5 minus its value, call it x
                           #&2           Create x copies of 2
                       7#:~              Convert 7 to base 2 and take the last x digits
                      ,                  Append those x digits to the end of A
                   |.@                   Reverse it, call it A'
^~                                       Power, reversed operators
    %~                                   Division, reversed operators
       *                                 Multiplication
         -~                              Subtraction, reversed operators
            +                            Addition
             /@                          Insert the previous operations, separated by `,
                                         into A' in order and cycle until the end
                                         Then evaluate the equation from right-to-left
                                         and return
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>81</s> <s>67</s> 64 bytes

```python
i=10
for n in input():exec'r%s=n'%'*+-*/*'[i::5];i=-~i%5
print r
```

Input is an array of floats. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/7HKWKV).

#### How it works

`'*+-*/*'[i::5]` selects every fifth character of the string, starting with the one at index **i**, so this yields `**` if **i = 0**, `+` if **i = 1**, `-` if **i = 2**, `*` if **i = 3** and `/` if **i = 4**. Since the string has length **6**, the expression will yield an empty string if **i > 5**.

We initialize the variable **i** to **10**. For each number **n** in the input array, we construct the string `r<op>=n`, which `exec` executes.

Initially, **i = 10**, so `<op>` is the empty string, and it initializes **r** with `r+=n`. After each step, we increment **i** modulo **5** with `i=-~i%5`, so the next step will retrieve the proper operator.

When all input numbers has been processed, and we print **r**, which holds the desired output.

Answer (score 5):

## Matlab - <strike>95 91</strike> 85 bytes / Octave - 81 bytes

Input is in such form: `a = ['1' '2' '3' '4' '5'];`, I hope this is covered by "string representing an array with integers/decimals", else there are 2 num2str needed additionally.

Every intermediate result gets printed to console because that saves me some semicolons. `a(1)` is executed so its value is then saved to `ans`. Also of course using `ans` in code is bad practice.

```
b='+-*/^'
a(1)
for i=2:length(a)
  ['(',ans,')',b(mod(i-2,5)+1),a(i)]
end
eval(ans)
```

In Octave, `'+-*/^'(mod(i+2,5)+1)` also works, which saves another 4 bytes, thanks Adám and Luis Mendo:

```
a(1)
for i=2:length(a)
  strcat('(',ans,')','+-*/^'(mod(i-2,5)+1),a(i))
end
eval(ans)
```

Changelog:

- Removed spaces where possible
- added Octave solution
- replaced strcat() with []

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! The input is fine like that, since it's still easily distinguishable what the input is. Hmm, I never used Matlab, so maybe I'm saying idiotic things here, but can't `b = '+-*/^'` be golfed to `b='+-*/^'` and `for i = 2:length(a)` to `for i=2:length(a)` (removing the spaces)? Also, perhaps [Tips for golfing in MATLAB](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12974/tips-for-golfing-in-matlab) might be interesting for you. :)

Comment: Is `'+-*/^'(mod(i+2,5)+1)` valid?

Comment: @Adám No, but it probably is in Octave

Comment: @Adám: it works in Octave, I added it.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>67</s> <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```
Fold[{+##,#-#2,#2#,#/#2,If[#2==0,1,#^#2]}[[i++~Mod~5+1]]&,i=0;#]&
```

Simple `Fold` with a variable `i` holding the index.

Comment: A byte can be saved by `+##` instead of `#+#2`

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 18 bytes

```
q~{"+-*/#"W):W=~}*
```

Input is an array of floats. [Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX57IistKi8jIlcpOlc9fn0q&input=Wy04LjAgNTAuMCAzLjAgMy4wIC0xMjMuMCA0LjAgMTcuMCA5OS4wIDEzLjBd)

#### How it works

```
q~                  Read and evaluate all input.
  {             }*  Reduce:
   "+-*/#"            Push the string of operators.
          W           Push W (initially -1).
           ):W        Increment and save in W.
              =       Retrieve the character at that index.
               ~      Evaluate.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>87 78</s> 70 bytes

```r
i=0
Reduce(function(a,j)get(substr("+-*/^",i<<-i%%5+1,i))(a,j),scan())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU/bCsIwDH3vVxwsg9at2rRmczB/wg8QdE6pDxPc9v0zDnxUDgkhORfymjUhIGIHhoZXmkEBIcpyJwgoUcmBY62024O9cCMchY@EKtQ1KArBkWfeRK6UFvlfaAQuleR6fEuDxL6GJDha3IQge7dYR5mdBC19Tgevjt11ajtzm/p2TM/enIuHvXejGabLML7MKnfr7WlVpKZxKcs4pyJZu7CKoT33xtr55zPzGw)

Comment: at some point I really need to learn how to use `do.call`...I probably shouldn't consider myself an R programmer until I do!

Comment: @Giuseppe [`Advanced R` by Hadley Wickam](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) is a great beach read :)

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks for pointing out `do.call` - made me realize I was looking for `get`.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>173</s> <s>172</s> <s>167</s> <s>138</s> <s>137</s> <s>118</s> 113 bytes

```java
a->{double r=a[0],t;for(int i=1;i<a.length;r=new double[]{Math.pow(r,t),r+t,r-t,r*t,r/t}[i++%5])t=a[i];return r;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lVBBbsIwELzzir1USho7JQmURm76A7hwRDm4wYBpcCJnA6pQ3p4uCajqrZZm7bVWMzvjozxLXtXKHLdffVHKpoGl1OY6AdAGld3JQsHq9gTYVu1nqaDwxmaTg/QFTToqQoMSdQErMJBBL/nH9U6wmdxMc4ZiV1mPVEFnkdDvMiyV2eNB2MyoCzxEr0uJh7CuLp5l6DMbILOc6pnqBbuNDoKnee4jiepcWIWtNWBF14sJmahJhEzcvZwrvYUT5fHWaLXZD5bHMOvvBtUprFoMaxphaTwTFt4fJxAxiBkkDGYM5tD5Q9x/cucMIiLHyaAxG0DNK4OFoxJ/o@3TwQeBR/FoKFowSFO6E0e9mLnAUZy@jKz@nq5ZKdAtL48cibSOJ87L0gejm3T9Dw)

```java
a->{                     // Method with double-array parameter and double return-type
  double r=a[0],         //  Result-double, starting at the first item of the input
         t;              //  Temp double
  for(int i=1;           //  Index-integer, starting at the second item
      i<a.length;        //  Loop over the input-array
      r=new double[]{    //    After every iteration, change `r` to:
         Math.pow(r,t),  //      If `i%5` is 0: `r^t`
         r+t,            //      Else-if `i%5` is 1: `r+t`
         r-t,            //      Else-if `i%5` is 2: `r-t`
         r*t,            //      Else-if `i%5` is 3: `r*t`
         r/t}[i++%5])    //      Else-if `i%5` is 4: `r/t`
                         //      And increase `i` by 1 afterwards with `i++`
    t=a[i];              //   Change `t` to the next item in the array
  return r;}             //  Return result-double
```

Comment: Because, ya know, java.1.5 times longer than the current longest answer....wich is in SQL

Comment: @Bálint That's Java for ya. :) [My shortest java answer so far is 65 bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80243/toggle-a-string/80250#80250) xD (and that wasn't really my answer, but *Leaky Nun*'s..)

Comment: Well, `float` is shorter than `double`.

Comment: You can change `double r=a[0];` to `double r=a[0],b;` to save some bytes.

Comment: You can change `i<a.length;i++` to `i++<a.length;` (you might have to change the order of the operations)

Comment: @LeakyNun Originally I had `float`, but there isn't a `Math.pow` for floats, hence the `double` instead. Thanks for the `,b`. And with `i++<a.length` I get an _ArrayOutOfBoundsException_ at `b=a[i];` (unless I do `i++<a.length-1` instead, which is one byte longer instead of shorter).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen This can be solved by `int i=0;++i<a.length;`.

Comment: You can change `== 4` to `> 3` and `== 0` to `< 1`.  I'm not sure but I think you could save a bit by creating a variable for `i % 5`.

Comment: I figured you can change the whole thing to a concatenation of ternaries. In all comparisons you can then use the `<x` trick, shrinking the whole function to 137 characters.

Comment: @Frozn Thanks, that saved a lot of bytes! Hmm, I get down to 144 bytes instead of 137. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: The last comparison `x < 5` isn't necessary, as the value can only be between 0 and 4. The other ternaries ensure that there is only the possibility of x == 4. So it should look like this: `[...] x < 4 ? r * s : r / s;`. I also used @LeakyNun 's tip, which saves another character.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell - 74

```
f(x:xs)=foldl(\x(o,y)->o x y)x(zip(cycle[(+),(-),(*),(/),flip(^).floor])xs)
```

Test cases:

```
λ> f[1,2,3,4,5] -> 0.0
λ> f[5,12,23,2,4,4,2,6,7] -> 539.0
λ> f[-8,50,3,3,-123,4,17,99,13] -> -1055.356943846277
λ> f [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] -> 256.0
```

It could probably be shorter; Haskell's support for infinite lists and higher order functions make the direct solution quite pleasant, though. A version of `^ :: Double -> Double -> Double` would be nicer for golfing, but I couldn't find one. Thankfully, I didn't need a full lambda, so pointless style shaved off a few bytes.

Comment: You can prepend a single `(+)` to the list of operators and start the `foldl` with `0` to go completely pointfree and save the function name and parameters: `foldl(\x(o,y)->o x y)0.zip((+):cycle[(+),(-),(*),(/),(**)])`.

Answer (score 3):

## Oracle PL/SQL, <s>275</s> 254 Bytes

```
declare r number;begin for x in (select n,mod(rownum,5)r from t) loop if r is null then r:=x.n;elsif x.r=2then r:=r+x.n;elsif x.r=3then r:=r-x.n;elsif x.r=4then r:=r*x.n;elsif x.r=0then r:=r/x.n;else r:=r**x.n;end if;end loop;DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r);end;
```

The data must be inserted in a table called `T` with a column `N` of type `NUMBER`

Usage:

```
drop table t;
create table t (n number);
insert into t values (-8);
insert into t values (50);
insert into t values (3);
insert into t values (3);
insert into t values (-123);
insert into t values (4);
insert into t values (17);
insert into t values (99);
insert into t values (13);

declare r number;begin for x in (select n,mod(rownum,5)r from t) loop if r is null then r:=x.n;elsif x.r=2then r:=r+x.n;elsif x.r=3then r:=r-x.n;elsif x.r=4then r:=r*x.n;elsif x.r=0then r:=r/x.n;else r:=r**x.n;end if;end loop;DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r);end;
```

Output:

```
-1055,356943846277162152071601242992595623
```

#### 275 Bytes version:

```
declare r number;cursor c is select n,mod(rownum,5) r from t;begin for x in c loop if r is null then r:=x.n;else case x.r when 2 then r:=r+x.n;when 3 then r:=r-x.n;when 4 then r:=r*x.n;when 0 then r:=r/x.n;else r:=r**x.n; end case;end if;end loop;DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r);end;
```

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v2+, 124 bytes

```
param($n)$o=$n[0];if($y=$n.count-1){1..$y|%{$o=if(($x=$i++%5)-4){"$o"+'+-*/'[$x]+$n[$_]|iex}else{[math]::pow($o,$n[$_])}}}$o
```

Long because PowerShell doesn't have a `^` or `**` operator, so we have to account for a separate case and use a .NET call.

Takes input `$n` as an array, sets our output `$o` to be the first digit. We then check the `.count` of the array, and so long as it's greater than one we enter the `if`. Otherwise, we skip the `if`.

Inside the `if` we loop through the array `1..$y|%{...}` and each iteration we re-set `$o` to a new value, the result of another `if/else` statement. So long as our counter `$i++` isn't modulo-5 equal to 4 (i.e., we're not at the `^` operator), we simply take `$o` and concatenate it with the appropriate symbol `'+-*/'[$x]` and the next number in the input array `$n[$_]`. We pipe that to `iex` (alias for `Invoke-Expression` and similar to `eval`), and that gets re-saved to `$o`. If we're on the `^` operator, we're in the `else`, so we execute a `[math]::Pow()` call, and *that* result gets re-saved back into `$o`.

In either case, we simply output `$o` to the pipeline and exit, with output implicit.

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, <strike>123</strike>, 117 bytes

Original answer:

```
fn a(v:&[f32])->f32{v.iter().skip(1).enumerate().fold(v[0],|s,(i,&x)|match i%5{0=>s+x,1=>s-x,2=>s*x,3=>s/x,_=>s.powf(x)})}
```

stupid long method names ^^
ahh much better

```
fn f(v:&[f32])->f32{v[1..].iter().zip(0..).fold(v[0],|s,(&x,i)|match i%5{0=>s+x,1=>s-x,2=>s*x,3=>s/x,_=>s.powf(x)})}
```

ungolfed

```
fn f(values : &[f32]) -> f32 {
    values[1..].iter().zip(0..)
    .fold(values[0], |state,(&x,i)|
        match i%5 {
            0=>state+x,
            1=>state-x,
            2=>state*x,
            3=>state/x,
            _=>state.powf(x)
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>88</s> 93 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:eval('('*(len(x)-1)+'){}'.join(map(str,x)).format(*['+','-','*','/','**']*len(x)))
```

It started off being much shorter but then operator precedence defeated me and I had to include lots of parenthesis...

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>70 68 65</s>  62 bytes

```
{$/=[(|(&[+],&[-],&[*],&[/],&[**])xx*)];.reduce: {$/.shift.($^a,$^b)}}
{(@_ Z |(&[+],&[-],&[*],&[/],&[**])xx*).flat.reduce: {&^b($^a,$^c)}}
{(@_ Z |(*+*,*-*,&[*],*/*,&[**])xx*).flat.reduce: {&^b($^a,$^c)}}
{reduce {&^b($^a,$^c)},flat @_ Z |(*+*,*-*,&[*],*/*,&[**])xx*}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
-> *@_ {
  reduce
    -> $a, &b, $c { b($a,$c) },

    flat       # flatten list produced from zip
      zip
        @_,    # input

        slip(  # causes the list of operators to flatten into the xx list

          # list of 5 infix operators
          &infix:<+>, &infix:<->, &infix:<*>, &infix:</>, &infix:<**>

        ) xx * # repeat the list of operators infinitely
}
```

Technically `* + *` is a Whatever lambda, but is effectively the same as `&[+]` which is short for `&infix:<+>` the set of subroutines that handle infix numeric addition.
I didn't use that for multiplication or exponentiation as the ways to write them like that is at least as long as what I have (`*×*` or `* * *` and `* ** *`)

#### Test:

Test it on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/dRHzhx)
(after they upgrade to a [Rakudo](https://rakudo.org) version that isn't from a year and a half before the official release of the [Perl 6](http://perl6.org) [spectests](https://github.com/perl6/roast))

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;
use Test;

my @tests = (
  [1,2,3,4,5] => 0,
  [5,12,23,2,4,4,2,6,7] => 539,
  [-8,50,3,3,-123,4,17,99,13] => -1055.35694385, # -2982186493/2825761
  [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] => 256,
  [1,0,1,0,1,0] => 1,
  [-9,-8,-1] => -16,
  [0,-3] => -3,
  [-99] => -99,
);

plan +@tests;

my &code = {reduce {&^b($^a,$^c)},flat @_ Z |(*+*,*-*,&[*],&[/],&[**])xx*}

for @tests -> $_ ( :key(@input), :value($expected) ) {
  is code(@input), $expected, .gist
}
```

```
1..8
ok 1 - [1 2 3 4 5] => 0
ok 2 - [5 12 23 2 4 4 2 6 7] => 539
ok 3 - [-8 50 3 3 -123 4 17 99 13] => -1055.35694385
ok 4 - [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2] => 256
ok 5 - [1 0 1 0 1 0] => 1
ok 6 - [-9 -8 -1] => -16
ok 7 - [0 -3] => -3
ok 8 - [-99] => -99
```

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##fVHbboMwDH3PV1gaqyA4LUkIEFCrfsTeEJ1Ym03VuhZxmVZV/XYWLtveJiuS7XN8fORUpj5F/ccVFvvLwcAaerqszaHbm/SWU58iZRQXOS2QrsaEFkXu@P4jLVxnV6Kze/HufUa6xsCTadqMWK1ta7PGirkEIOcoUGKIqoD1BgIcegq5QCEtEtoQGGE8okrqEWcJqsBOSWRcDMM8Rq2Ry5HFeKDUUqpIhzJRCA/AhE4ET6JQy5VIhIojPsjYHf/FKCZUhJPNAOc39vlkRKP1wvi8d6IGyGYjcibpqbQWiZcRINWpPIM/3WGoXy/1z1XYBpxncCF9N1d3ezxXXeshpJ/lqTOuY74qs2/NwQMPblb72MDwMX/EXwbC8u3YtOTefwM)

Answer (score 3):

A few tricks can reduce @Willmore´s approach by 23 to 174 bytes (requires php 5.6 or later). The most saving part is removing unneccessary parentheses (-10 bytes).

> function f($a){while(count($a)>1){$l=array_shift($a);$r=array_shift($a);array_unshift($a,($j=$i++%5)?($j==1?$l-$r:($j==2?$l*$r:($j==3?$l/$r:$l**$r))):$l+$r);}return end($a);}

But using the `**` operator instead of `pow()` also allows to use `eval` with an array for the operations; and with a few more tricks ...

## PHP >= 5.6, 82 bytes

```php
while(--$argc)eval('$x'.['/','**','+','-','*'][$i++?$i%5:2]."=$argv[$i];");echo$x;
```

takes list from command line parameters. Run with `php -nr '<code>'` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/233f2ac985a4d668abfabc0411a2b48936e6ce63).

### old version, <s>161 157 151 145 144 140 137</s> 117 bytes

```php
function f($a){while(count($a)>1)eval('$a[0]=array_shift($a)'.['+','-','*','/','**'][$i++%5].'$a[0];');return$a[0];}
```

The most effective golfing came from writing the intermediate result directly to the first element - after shifting the previous result from the array.

**breakdown**

```php
function f($a)
{
    while(count($a)>1)  // while array has more than one element ...
        eval('$a[0]='                           // future first element :=
            . 'array_shift($a)'                 // = old first element (removed)
            . ['+','-','*','/','**'][$i++%5]    // (operation)
            .'$a[0];'                           // new first element (after shift)
        );
    return$a[0];        // return last remaining element
}
```

**test suite**

```php
$cases = array (
    0=>[1,2,3,4,5],
    539=>[5,12,23,2,4,4,2,6,7],
    '-1055.356...' => [-8,50,3,3,-123,4,17,99,13],
    256 => [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    1 => [1,0,1,0,1,0],
    -16 => [-9,-8,-1],
    -3 => [0, -3],
    -99 => [-99]
);
echo '<table border=1><tr><th>values</th><th>expected</th><th>actual result</th></tr>';
foreach ($cases as $expect=>$a)
{
    $result=f($a);
    echo "<tr><td>[", implode(',',$a),"]</td><td>$expect</td><td>$result</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Nicely done.  You could remove 3 more bytes by returning the last value as an array (change 'return $a[0]' to 'return$a'), which I'm not seeing is specifically against the rules. :)

Comment: @gwaugh Imo `If the array contains just a single number, we return that as the result.` is pretty clear. But thanks for letting me revisit this.

Comment: One could make a semantic argument that the "that" in the sentence can refer to "the array".  Regardless, your answer is by far the shortest PHP.  Very nicely done, and thx again for pointers on my longer submission.

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>135</del> 130 bytes

Thanks @titus, -5 bytes, plus 0 case fix!

```php
function f($z){return array_reduce($z,function($c,$x)use(&$i){eval('$c'.['/','**','+','-','*'][$i++?$i%5:5].'=$x;');return$c;});};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDfT4MwEMef17/islRLxzEHDCdW3JOJDybunTQL6UogmUD4YaYLfzsrynw0d9/L966fXJtWWTU8bStT065QbV4WkFr0m59r3XZ1AUldJ1/7Wh86pc0cr5RFFdIT7xpt3dKcn/VncrQYVWwZszuGbLEwxTZyxobJmOa2vaX5TfAYyCWL6EkwLn4voUr0XPRiILTVTdtABDGZxRAguB6C5xshrH/SmHuEDUgcCecBgxX6JhzXYGt0NxiG6PrTuYf/xkS5uMJJ170hmtWO@9eGIIkUhKRlrROVWTC9NGmMAw5nMtMqK4HFwBDyj@pYHrQ1epMjgTAHCdEzzNF88DTave72L@9vgvRkuAA)

Less golfy:

```php
function f( $t ) {
    return array_reduce( $t,
        function( $c, $x ) use( &$i ) {
            eval('$c'.['/','**','+','-','*'][$i++?$i%5:5].'=$x;');
            return $c;
        }
    );
};
```

Was really rooting for array_reduce() to work for this, but requires too many chars to beat the current lowest PHP score.

Posting it anyway in case anyone has any suggestions!

Comment: Nice approach; but I reckon it will fail whenever `$c` hits `0`. Save two bytes with an anonymous function instead of `w`. `eval('$c'.['/','**','+','-','*'][$i++?$i%5:5].'=$x');return$c;` is six bytes shorter and should resolve the zero issue.

Comment: Thanks @Titus! You are absolutely right about the 0 case. I had to add back the ; after the =$x because eval wouldn't run without it. If I made it an anon function I'd have to have a variable assignment to it or run it within the test code, right? Wouldn't want to call the byte count into question. :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 68 bytes

```
hI,?bL,1:+:-:*:/:^b:L:I{bhv?t.|[O:L:I]h$(P,LbM,OhA,Lh:Ir:A&:M:Pr&.}.
```

That's long… but it uses no evaluation predicate.

#### Explanation

- Main predicate

  ```
  hI,                                  Unify I with the first element of the input
     ?bL,                              L is the input minus the first element
         1:+:-:*:/:^b                  Construct the list of predicates [+:-:*:/:^]
                     :L:I{...}.        Call predicate 1 with [[+:-:*:/:^]:L:I] as input
  ```
- Predicate 1

  ```
  bhv?t.                               If the second element of Input is empty (i.e. L),
                                       unify Output with the last element of Input
  |                                    Or
  [O:L:I]                              Input = [O:L:I]
         h$(P,                         P is O circularly permutated to the left
              LbM,                     M is L minus the first element
                  OhA,                 A is the first element of O
                      Lh:Ir:A&         Call predicate A on [I:First element of L]
                              :M:Pr&.  Call predicate 1 recursively with P:M:
  ```

Comment: Beat you by 1̶ ̶b̶y̶t̶e̶ 2 bytes ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>29</s> 27 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anomymous tacit prefix function. Note that `*` is exponentiation in APL.

```apl
≢{⍎3↓⍕⌽⍵,¨⍨⍺⍴'+-×÷*',¨'⍨'}⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HnoupHvX3Gj9omP@qd@qhn76PerTqHVjzqBaJdj3q3qGvrHp5@eLuWOlBQHSiqXvuoa9H/tEdtE4C6HvVN9fR/1NV8aD1Q/0QgLzjIGUiGeHgG/09TMNQx0jHWMdEx5UpTMNUxNNIxMgaKmAChkY6ZjjlQ9NB6Cx1TA6AiY51D6w2NQIoNzXUsLXUMjYGyQA34IBfIBgMdKAabZqkDMhFoFJBnAKSNIaKWAA)

Because APL executes right to left, we can just reverse the order of arguments of the inserted operations and reverse the entire expression. Postfix `⍨` reverses arguments. After doing a perfect shuffle of numbers and operations, we only just need to reverse, flatten, and evaluate:

`≢{`…`}⊢` call the following function with count of and actual numbers as `⍺` and `⍵`:

`'⍨'` this character

`'+-×÷*',¨` prepend each of these characters to that; `["+⍨","-⍨","×⍨","÷⍨","*⍨"]`

`⍺⍴` use the left argument (count of numbers) to cyclically **r**eshape that

`⌽` reverse

`⍕` format as flat string

`3↓` drop leading 3 characters (a space and a symbol and `⍨`)

`⍎` execute as APL code

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 + 8087 FPU, 65 bytes

```
00000000: 9bdf 04ad 499b de04 ad49 e334 9bde 24ad  ....I....I.4..$.
00000010: 49e3 2d9b de0c ad49 e326 9bde 34ad 49e3  I.-....I.&..4.I.
00000020: 1fad 919b d9e8 85c9 7413 9c7f 02f7 d99b  ........t.......
00000030: d8c9 e2fb 9d7d 069b d9e8 9bd8 f191 e2c5  .....}..........
00000040: c3                                       .
```

Callable function: input array at `DS:SI`, length in `CX`. Output to `ST` top 8087 register stack.

Listing:

```
9B DF 04    FILD    WORD PTR [SI]   ; load first item to 8087 stack 
AD          LODSW 
49          DEC     CX 
                 
        CALC:
            ; Add 
9B DE 04    FIADD   WORD PTR [SI]   ; add 
AD          LODSW                   ; SI = next input 
49          DEC     CX              ; decrement counter 
E3 34       JCXZ    WOMI_DONE       ; exit if end of input array 
                 
            ; Subtract 
9B DE 24    FISUB   WORD PTR [SI]   ; subtract 
AD          LODSW                   ; SI = next input 
49          DEC     CX 
E3 2D       JCXZ    WOMI_DONE 
                 
            ; Multiply 
9B DE 0C    FIMUL   WORD PTR [SI]   ; multiply 
AD          LODSW                   ; SI = next input 
49          DEC     CX 
E3 26       JCXZ    WOMI_DONE 
                 
            ; Divide 
9B DE 34    FIDIV   WORD PTR [SI]   ; divide 
AD          LODSW                   ; SI = next input
49          DEC     CX 
E3 1F       JCXZ    WOMI_DONE 
                 
            ; Exponent 
AD          LODSW                   ; AX = exponent, SI = next input 
91          XCHG    AX, CX          ; CX = counter for loop (exponent), save CX 
9B D9 E8    FLD1                    ; load 1 into ST 
85 C9       TEST    CX, CX          ; is exponent pos, neg or 0? 
74 13       JZ      EXP_DONE        ; exit (with value 1) if exponent is 0 
9C          PUSHF                   ; save result flags for later 
7F 02       JG      EXP_REP         ; if exp > 1 start calculation 
F7 D9       NEG     CX              ; make exponent positive for loop 
        EXP_REP: 
9B D8 C9    FMUL    ST(0), ST(1)    ; multiply ST0 = ST0 * ST1 
E2 FB       LOOP    EXP_REP 
9D          POPF                    ; restore sign flag from earlier 
7D 06       JGE     EXP_DONE        ; if exponent was neg, divide 1 by result 
9B D9 E8    FLD1                    ; push 1 into numerator 
9B D8 F1    FDIV    ST(0), ST(1)    ; ST0 = 1 / ST1 
        EXP_DONE: 
91          XCHG    AX, CX          ; restore CX 
                 
E2 C5       LOOP    CALC            ; if more input, start again 
             
        WOMI_DONE: 
C3          RET
```

Sample Output:

[image]

Comment: This is great! I've written a similar solution for x86-64 (linux) but I haven't golfed it much yet which will probably change a lot of the logic around.

For your exponent calculation, even though the tests given don't test receiving a negative exponent, I felt that it was a necessary part of the program logic, especially since it's as simple as pushing 1 to st0 and then doing a div between st0 and st1 (at least on x86 this is two instructions).

Comment: Thanks @davey -- very good point!  I've updated the code to handle negative exponents and added another test case for it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 16 bytes

```
r@[XY]r"p+-*/"gZ
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ckBbWFldciJwKy0qLyJnWg==&input=Wy04LDUwLDMsMywtMTIzLDQsMTcsOTksMTNd)

Explanation:

```
r@                  #Reduce the input list:
       "p+-*/"      # The list of functions to apply (offset by one due to the behavior of Z)
              gZ    # Choose the one at the current index, wrapping
  [  ]r             # Apply that function to:
   X                #  The result of the previous step
    Y               #  and the current number
                    #Implicitly return the result of the final step
```

Comment: Ah, feck, was just working on this myself, trying to figure out why it was giving me incorrect results - I'd missed the fecking exponentiation! :\

Answer (score 1):

## c#, <s>238</s>, 202 bytes

```
double d(double[]a){Array.Reverse(a);var s=new Stack<double>(a);int i=0,j;while(s.Count>1){double l=s.Pop(),r=s.Pop();j=i++%5;s.Push(j==0?l+r:j==1?l-r:j==2?l*r:j==3?l/r:Math.Pow(l,r));}return s.Peek();}
```

I didn't see any c# solution so I will give one. This is my first codegolf. I started writing in c# ["two months ago"](https://github.com/spookiecookie/NaturalLanguageDateTime/commit/7a74025562947fb8a784ac2ecdf2f9181782741a) (though I know Java to some extent).

It uses **Stack**

[image: Try online!]

**Ungolfed and test cases**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class M 
{
    double d(double[]a) {
        Array.Reverse(a);
        var s = new Stack<double>(a);
        int i=0,j;
        while (s.Count>1)
        {
            double l=s.Pop(),r=s.Pop();
            j=i++%5;
            s.Push(j==0?l+r:j==1?l-r:j==2?l*r:j==3?l/r:Math.Pow(l, r));
        }
        return s.Peek();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int[][] a = new int[][]{
            new int[]{1,2,3,4,5},
            new int[]{5,12,23,2,4,4,2,6,7},
            new int[]{-8,50,3,3,-123,4,17,99,13},
            new int[]{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
            new int[]{1,0,1,0,1,0},
            new int[]{-9,-8,-1},
            new int[]{0,-3},
            new int[]{-99}
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new M().d(Array.ConvertAll(a[i], e => Convert.ToDouble(e))));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
539
-1055,35694384628
256
1
-16
-3
-99
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! This might be a nice topic to look at: [Tips for code-golfing in C#](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c). Some things that can be golfed down in your code: spaces (`a, Double.Parse` -> `a,Double.Parse`; `while (s.Count` -> `while(s.Count`; `Pow(l, r)` -> `Pow(l,r)`). Also, you can remove `int ` in front of the `j=` and put it behind the `int i=0,j;`. Great first answer though, and once again welcome. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Hi! Ty!  Spaces removed and j moved as you suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>206</s>,<s>198</s>,197 bytes

```
function f($a){while(count($a)>1){$l=array_shift($a);$r=array_shift($a);array_unshift($a,($j=$i++%5)==0?($l+$r):($j==1?($l-$r):($j==2?($l*$r):($j==3?($l/$r):(pow($l,$r))))));}return array_pop($a);}
```

[image: Try online!]

**Ungolfed**

```
<?php
 
function f($a)
{
    while(count($a)>1)
    {
        $l = array_shift($a); $r = array_shift($a);
        array_unshift($a,($j=$i++%5)==0?($l+$r):($j==1?($l-$r):($j==2?($l*$r):($j==3?($l/$r):(pow($l,$r))))));
    }
    return array_pop($a);
}
 
echo f([1,2,3,4,5])."\n";
echo f([5,12,23,2,4,4,2,6,7])."\n";
echo f([-8,50,3,3,-123,4,17,99,13])."\n";
echo f([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2])."\n";
echo f([1,0,1,0,1,0])."\n";
echo f([-9,-8,-1])."\n";
echo f([0,-3])."\n";
echo f([-99])."\n";
```

In PHP, logic similar to my c# [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83043/55472) (**202 bytes**) :) .

Answer (score 1):

## Emacs Lisp, 127 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(let((f'(+ - * / expt))(a(float(car x)))(x(cdr x)))(dotimes(i(length x)a)(set'a(funcall(nth(mod i 5)f)a(nth i x))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(lambda(x)
  (let ((f'(+ - * / expt))  ; list of functions in order they are called
        (a (float (car x))) ; initial value
        (x (cdr x)))        ; 
    (dotimes (i (length x) a)
      (set 'a (funcall (nth (mod i 5) f) ; call the i % 5th function
                       a                 ; with accumulator
                       (nth i x))))))    ; and the ith value
```

Testcases:

```
(-map
  (lambda(x)(let((f'(+ - * / expt))(a(float(car x)))(x(cdr x)))(dotimes(i(length x)a)(set'a(funcall(nth(mod i 5)f)a(nth i x))))))
  '((1 2 3 4 5)
    (5 12 23 2 4 4 2 6 7)
    (-8 50 3 3 -123 4 17 99 13)
    (2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2)
    (1 0 1 0 1 0)
    (-9 -8 -1)
    (0 -3)
    (-99)))
```

Output:

```
(0.0 539.0 -1055.356943846277 256.0 1.0 -16.0 -3.0 -99.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```ruby
->a{i=0;a.reduce{|x,y|x.send %w[** + - * /][(i+=1)%5],y}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU3LDoIwELz7Fb2QKEyxLVRoDP5I0wMqJFyMwRAhwLfXQizezGRnd2f20XbXwdaFpZdybAp2LuO2une3apx6DFMfv6rHnQRvHYYkIpSE5Gj0vokKfgikwTDP9klqrTkEEqSQxuxWQYILiMTJqYPACZm3aB4zEMkWTjaiXKw5XYhnCyu11k72q@7kP/gxDoZvbE8VaA7Kfc9Ak5@njLEf)

Takes an array of floats, but also works with integers, as long as all division results are integer.

At first, I tried fiddling with `eval` which looks like the obvious approach, but it gets rather verbose. Instead, I opted for `send`, which is basically Ruby's way to call methods by names, so that `x.send("+",y)` is equivalent to `x+y`.

Answer (score 1):

## shell script, <s>157</s> <s>135</s> <s>133</s> <s>130</s> <s>124</s> <s>99</s> <s>95</s> <s>88</s> <s>85</s> 81 bytes

golfed (bash/non-posix) - 81 bytes

```
f()(A=$1;S=+-*/^;shift;for B;{ C=${S:((I++%5)):1};A=`bc -l<<<$A$C$B`;};echo $A)
```

golfed (portable/posix, using 'cut'-operator) - 118 bytes

```
f()(S=+-x/^;A=$1;shift;for B;do C=`echo $S|cut -b1`;S=`echo $S|cut -b2-5`;S="$S$C";A=`echo $A$C$B|bc -l`;done;echo $A)
```

golfed (portable/posix, with builtins) - 124 bytes

```
f()(A=$1;shift;for B;do case $I in 1)C=-;;2)C=*;;3)C=/;;4)C=^;;*)C=+;I=;;esac;I=$((I+1));A=`echo $A$C$B|bc -l`;done;echo $A)
```

ungolfed (posix - with builtins):

```
A=$1
shift
for B;do
case $I in
1)C=-;;
2)C=*;;
3)C=/;;
4)C=^;;
*)C=+;I=
esac
I=$((I+1))
A=`echo $A$C$B|bc -l`
done
echo $A
```

ungolfed (posix - with 'cut'):

```
S=+-x/^
A=$1
shift
for B;do
C=`echo $S|cut -b1`
S=`echo $S|cut -b2-5`
S="$S$C"
A=`echo $A$C$B|bc -l`
done
echo $A
```

This is *unfair*!
We don't have real division in language 'sh',
so we must use 'bc' which is...lame 8-)
**hint:** your directory must have no files, otherwise the asterisk expands to filenames (◔_◔)

## Tests:

```
# f 1 2 3 4 5
0
# f 5 12 23 2 4 4 2 6 7
539
# f -8 50 3 3 -123 4 17 99 13
-1055.35
# f 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
256.00
# f 1 0 1 0 1 0
1
# f -9 -8 -1
-16
# f 0 -3
-3
# f -99
-99
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>29</s> <s>28</s> 27 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

**Using 'Python `eval`' builtin (<s>29</s> <s>28</s> 27 bytes):**

```
g'(×svy')"+-*/"S„**ªNè}\J.E
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/XV3j8PTiskp1TSVtXS19peBHDfO0tA7tOLTa7/CK2hgvPdf//6N1LXRMDXSMgVDX0MhYx0TH0FzH0lLH0DgWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/3R1jcPTi8sq1TWVtHW19JWCHzXM09I6tOPQar/DK2pjvPRc/@v8j4421DHSMdYx0TGN1VGINtUxNNIxMgYKmQChkY6ZjjlIWNdCx9QAqMpYR9fQCKTY0FzH0lLH0BgkCdSAD4KUGOoY6EAx2DhLHaCJuoYgtoGOrjFEzBJMgZyjC3FPLAA). (NOTE: `ª` is `¸«` and we use the legacy version in the TIO, because `.E` is disabled in the new version of 05AB1E on TIO.)

**Using 'Execute as 05AB1E' builtin (<s>29</s> 28 bytes):**

```
vyD0‹i¦'(}N_iðë"m+-*/"Nè]J.V
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/rNLF4FHDzsxDy9Q1av3iMw9vOLxaKVdbV0tfye/wilgvvbD//6N1LXRMDXSMgVDX0MhYx0TH0FzH0lLH0DgWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfSWQ42LwqGFn5qFl6hq1fvGZhzccXq2Uq62rpa/kd3hFba2XXth/nf/R0YY6RjrGOiY6prE6CtGmOoZGOkbGQCETIDTSMdMxBwnrWuiYGgBVGevoGhqBFBua61ha6hgagySBGvBBkBJDHQMdKAYbZ6kDNFHXEMQ20NE1hohZgimQc3Qh7okFAA).

**Explanation:**

In Python `**` is used for exponentiation. In addition, `*`,`/`,`**` have operator precedence over `+`,`-`. So the code transforms `[-1,2,-3,4,-5]` to `(((((-1)+2)--3)*4)**-5)`, and then uses `.E` to execute the string as Python `eval`.

```python
g                  # Take the length of the (implicit) input
 '(×              '# Create a string of "(" characters of that size
s                  # Swap so the (implicit) input is at the top of the stack again
 v            }    # Loop `y` of each of its items:
  y                #  Push `y`
   ')             '#  Push ")"
     "+-*/"S       #  Push ["+","-","*","/"]
            „**ª   #  Append a trailing "**": ["+","-","*","/","**"]
                Nè #  Get a string from this list based on the index of the loop
                   #  (with automatic wraparound)
\                  # Discard the trailing operand from the stack
 J                 # Join all strings on the stack together
  .E               # Execute as Python eval (and output implicitly)
```

In 05AB1E negative values are with a trailing `(` instead of leading `-`, and `m` is used for exponentiation. In addition, a Polish notation is used. So the program transforms `[-1,2,-3,4,-5]` to `1( 2+3-4*5(m`, and then uses `.V` to execute the string as 05AB1E code.

```python
v                  # Loop `y` of each of its items:
 y                 #  Push `y`
  D0‹i   }         #  If `y` is negative:
      ¦            #   Remove the first character (the minus sign)
       '(         '#   And push a "("
  N_i              #  If the index of the loop is 0:
     ð             #   Push a space character
    ë              #  Else:
     "m+-*/"Nè     #   Push a character from "m+-*/" based on the index of the loop
                   #   (with automatic wraparound)
]                  # Close both the if-else and loop
 J                 # Join all strings on the stack together
  .V               # Execute as 05AB1E code (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
ćsvy"+-*/m"Nè.V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SHtxWaWStq6Wfq6S3@EVemH//0eb6hga6RgZ6xjpmAChkY6ZjnksAA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/h5hL6/0h7cVmlkrauln6ukt/hFXph/2sj7JUUdO0UlOx1/kcb6hjpGOuY6JjGckWb6hga6RgZA0VMgNBIx0zHHCiqa6FjagBUY6yja2gEUmpormNpqWNoDJQDKscHgSoMdQx0oBhklqUO0DhdQyDTQEfXGCxiGQsA)

**Explanation**

```
ć                # extract the head of the input list
 sv              # for each (value y, index N) in the rest of the list
   y             # push the element
    "+-*/m"Nè    # push a string representation of the Nth operator (wraps around)
             .V  # execute it as code
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 130 bytes

Without LINQ.

```cs
s=>{var x=s[0];for(var j=1;j<s.Length;j++){int t=j%5;var z=s[j];x=t<1?x=Math.Pow(x,z):t<2?x+=z:t<3?x-=z:t<4?x*=z:x/=z;}return x;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU9NT8JAEL33V0xITFq7rZQPtW6XHkw8QULiwQP2UMoK28Cu7m5hbdPfXhck0ZORzNebzJuXmUIFhZC0qxTja3j@VJrusPO7C6eMf2Cn2OZKwVyKtcx3jQPwXi23rAClc23LXrAVzHLGXe84BHiqeJGshCXRRYbgG01gCaRTZNLscwmGqEU/w29Cuse2JBEuExVOKV/rDS5932sY16BJeTXGR0ZtF8oMG6KTKDVklutNOBcH16Dae9DJIDU@qS0YpiY4gVFqri0wN6TGraS6khwMbnHnnH97FFyJLQ1fJNPUXbqcHs6nLuKsCe4RjPsIhicPooHNIwTRHYI4tnUIref3XnnPw/8QjG6zZoD@tEvkrFqE@ugcFx1iP4vjnw2ntdZ9AQ)

Comment: [84](https://tio.run/##fU69DoJADN59ii4mIAX5EfWCkLg4aeLmQG4AvCDEHAkcgUB4djyRVdJ@bYfvp0mlJ1U2XmqenJ5FHb9ZSBF@VwAx@GPlB33GBeS@6ZVM1CWHyjinacnSSDBFabFT/YCzJqR9q3XY6hIbiW2Ht0i8jHvRTKQhzDVt7VLVG0Zv9Sgzwa4ZZ0qsSPEcGRLa60cE10RwptYtW84dgnVAIERuBwZV/Wtg7Wlv42ItyaXaQhNnLAbJTwn5MsYP) - use the interpreter because it imports LINQ (among other commonly used core libraries) for free

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 64 bytes

```
R31B~~?@+31B~~?@S-31B~~?@*31B~~?@S,31B~~?@Sp
\i<{1[lil1-{S{)]{{B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/I2NCprs7eQRtKB@tCGVowAR0Yo4ArJtOm2jA6JzPHULc6uFoztrra6f9/UwVDIwUjYwUjBRMgNFIwUzAHAA)

First line is the main program loop, which reads a number from input and performs the next math instruction. If no input, the attack is dumped to the output and the program terminates. Entry point is the `<` on the second line, which reads the first number from input prior to entering the main loop. Invalid input blindly accepted with unpredictable results (only + and * are defined for strings, other operations would result in an empty stack).

Woo, finally found a use for `B`ranch command! The second line starting at index 3 acts like a function. In this case it takes in input, checks that it got input, and arranges the stack for return. Then `31B~~` invokes and cleans up after the invokation (as the `B`ranch instruction leaves 2 values on top of the stack, add a return pointer). All told the overhead (8+5n) was less than in-line (9n). I think I'll be adding a modifier that cause `B` to not push those 2 values (overhead of 2 bytes to save 2n bytes). Happily, no directional commands are needed to insure consistent execution.

Also featured is the `[` and `]` stack-of-stacks commands, which lets the program temporarily remove the return location from the stack as it handles reading input. It saves several bytes worth of stack manipulation having to otherwise work around those 2 values. These do enforce a maximum input list of 9 values. Changing the entry to `y<<` increases that to 19 items (and as `<` acts like a NOP, the branch pointer doesn't need to update). [A third line](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/I2NCprs7eQRtKB@tCGVowAR0Yo4ArNLPSxqbaMDonM8dQtzq4WjO2utqJKwYo@P@/qYKhkYKRsYKRggkQGimYKZgDAA) with `\y<<` (changing the existing `\` to `U`) would double that again to 39 items.

Stack at the end of the Branch "function" would look like `[v,i,1,x,y]` where `x,y` are at the top and the 0-indexed location on the first line (`y` will always be 0) where the next instruction with execute. `v` is the value that started on the stack prior to entry into the Branch "function". And `i` is the value read from input. If no input was available, `[i,1]` would instead be `[0]` resulting in `v` being printed when `?@` is reached.

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code (Linux), 90 bytes

```
0000000000000000 <weapons_asm>:
   0:   48 89 f1                mov    %rsi,%rcx
   3:   db 07                   fildl  (%rdi)

0000000000000005 <math_loop>:
   5:   48 83 c7 04             add    $0x4,%rdi
   9:   48 ff c9                dec    %rcx
   c:   e3 49                   jrcxz  57 <done>
   e:   da 07                   fiaddl (%rdi)
  10:   48 83 c7 04             add    $0x4,%rdi
  14:   48 ff c9                dec    %rcx
  17:   e3 3e                   jrcxz  57 <done>
  19:   da 27                   fisubl (%rdi)
  1b:   48 83 c7 04             add    $0x4,%rdi
  1f:   48 ff c9                dec    %rcx
  22:   e3 33                   jrcxz  57 <done>
  24:   da 0f                   fimull (%rdi)
  26:   48 83 c7 04             add    $0x4,%rdi
  2a:   48 ff c9                dec    %rcx
  2d:   e3 28                   jrcxz  57 <done>
  2f:   da 37                   fidivl (%rdi)
  31:   48 83 c7 04             add    $0x4,%rdi
  35:   48 ff c9                dec    %rcx
  38:   e3 1d                   jrcxz  57 <done>

000000000000003a <exp_rept>:
  3a:   51                      push   %rcx
  3b:   8b 0f                   mov    (%rdi),%ecx
  3d:   d9 e8                   fld1
  3f:   83 f9 00                cmp    $0x0,%ecx
  42:   74 10                   je     54 <exp_rept.done>
  44:   9c                      pushfq
  45:   7f 02                   jg     49 <exp_rept.l>
  47:   f7 d9                   neg    %ecx

0000000000000049 <exp_rept.l>:
  49:   d8 c9                   fmul   %st(1),%st
  4b:   e2 fc                   loop   49 <exp_rept.l>
  4d:   9d                      popfq
  4e:   7d 04                   jge    54 <exp_rept.done>
  50:   d9 e8                   fld1
  52:   de f9                   fdivrp %st,%st(1)

0000000000000054 <exp_rept.done>:
  54:   59                      pop    %rcx
  55:   eb ae                   jmp    5 <math_loop>

0000000000000057 <done>:
  57:   dd 1a                   fstpl  (%rdx)
  59:   c3
```

Firstly, credit to [gwaugh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178491/56718) which is also submitted for this post. I started working on this solution before gwaugh posted, which can be seen in my git repo's log, but ultimately his approach to this problem was the most efficient (especially the exponentiation). If you feel inclined to upvote my submission, please check out his as well.

Like my other x86 solutions, this code is simply a function that's meant to be called from a C/C++ program, which can be seen at [my git repo](https://github.com/Davey-Hughes/ppcg/tree/master/weapons_math_instruction). This means that the input array, length, and return pointer are passed through rdi, rsi, and rdx. For x86-64, getting the output location as an argument saves bytes, because normally when a C/C++ function returns a double on this processor, it's passed back through xmm0. This means the result double has to be moved from the FPU stack to a place in memory, then moved into xmm0. If we specify a place in memory we want the result, then we can just move the result double directly from the FPU stack to the memory location.

Exponentiation is done through repeated multiplication, with the assumption that we'll only get integer exponents (though the exponent can be negative). If the problem requires handling floating point exponentiation, the solution becomes extremely complicated. The standard way to compute x^y on x86 is to compute 2^(y * log2(x)). However, if x is negative (which happens in test case 2), log2(x) is a complex number, which can't be directly handled by the FPU. If you're curious how pow(double x, double y) is solved in C, check out the [glibc code here](https://repo.or.cz/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c#l280) (hint: it's complicated).

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 42 bytes

```
{*x{?[x;0 2;y/]}/(#1_x)#(+;-;*;%;{*/y#x})}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#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)

Sets up a reduce with the original input as `x`, and a corresponding list of operations to apply.

- `(+;-;*;%;{*/y#x})` initialize a list of the desired operations to apply, using `{*/y#x}` for pow (only works for raising values to integer powers)
- `(#1_x)#...` "overtake" this list, expanding it to match the length of the input `x` minus one (as the operations are applied *between* elements of `x`)
- `x{...}/...` set up the reduce, seeded with the original input and run over the list of operations to apply

  - `?[x;0 2;y/]` use `?[x;i;f] splice` to apply the operation between the first two elements of the input, replacing those values with the result of applying the operation (`y`) between them

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 135 bytes

```c
#include<math.h>
float r(float*a,int l){float z,v=*a;for(int p=1;p<l;v=(float[]){z?pow(v,z):1,v+z,v-z,v*z,v/z}[p++%5])z=a[p];return v;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY3daoMwFMfvfYrQUUj0WBet7Vx0exDnRUi1FfwIJnWg5NXnYgvb3bpzOBz48f8Q/lmI5anuRHM9lShV@lT3u8vbD0pbri8WOFXTc40GfPsuh7rTqCHzHU8wZi5nVT/glcuMMpk2bMzu8rwg8/Qu@088wkReKYyedfj2XHvBZHLpedu4IFPGc1mwodTXoUMjM8sa1/K6w8SZHWQnCFTflkiXSiPBVal2NywHq6zwZlt9dBsY8G8xhRAi2ENsICaEPVDHQEMII@vZ2w3hAEcDyWOf/wLxs@2JwKfhWkePkCRAo3@5beVfa4Ae1hCzfImq4We1@E37DQ)

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##jU3LasMwELznK0QgIMWrupKjpEb1l7g@CGGFgB9CUlyw0a/XVdxDb013WNidndnR9Kr1ulppulEF5LCCjmzzUcnlh5xhqtJmRodtxaR97@RU4e1WN2Sx4yeeYCYwZUlJUx9T53OsbZYdREPmStW2ka4NdzegScb1NgTUq9uAyW7ZoVR57se@RaH1AWnlW/@y0dYlpcH7g/kY9uDwbygDDgWcQEQQhMgnagGMAy@S55TA4QyXCOVzH30D8ZpyCqCMP@LYBcoSWPEvd4r8CxHY@fEkrl/adOrqV9r13w "C (gcc) – Try It Online")