# Convert YYYYMM to MMMYY

Tags: code-golf, string, date

Basing on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964715/convert-yyyymm-to-mmmyy).

Challenge is rather simple: given a date period in the format `YYYYMM` output it in the format `MMMYY`.

#### Rules:

- The input will be a number or a string exactly 6 characters long, consisting only of digits.
- Last two digits will be between `01` and `12`.
- Output must be in the form `MMMYY`, where `MMM` represents uppercase three-letter code for the month (below) and `YY` represents **two** last digits of the `YYYY` part of the input.

List of months with corresponding code:

```
MM    MMM
01    JAN
02    FEB
03    MAR
04    APR
05    MAY
06    JUN
07    JUL
08    AUG
09    SEP
10    OCT
11    NOV
12    DEC
```

#### Examples:

```
Input     Output
201604    APR16
200001    JAN00
000112    DEC01
123405    MAY34
```

Comment: This question is very well-balanced. Both manual parsing and date libraries end up being about the same, at least in Python.

Comment: Yesterday, I saw "Convert YYYYMM to MMMYY" on HNQ beside the SO logo. Now I see the same title beside the PCG logo. I was very confused :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## MATL, <s>18</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
4e!Z{Zc12XOXk
```

Input is provided as a string (enclosed in single quotes).

This version only runs in MATL on MATLAB since MATLAB is able to automatically parse `datestr('2016 04')`.

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a string
4e!     % Reshape input to be 2 x 4 (puts the year in row 1 and month in row 2)
Z{      % Place each row in a separate cell
Zc      % Join them together using a space to create 'yyyy mm' format
12      % Number literal, pre-defined datestring of 'mmmyy'
XO      % Convert from serial date number to string using this format
Xk      % Convert to uppercase
        % Implicitly display
```

---

Here is an **18 byte** version which works on Octave (and therefore the online interpreter)

```
'yyyymm'2$YO12XOXk
```

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J3l5eXltbScyJFlPMTJYT1hr&input=JzIwMTYwNCc)

[Modified version for all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YCd5eXl5bW0nMiRZTzEyWE9Ya0RU&input=JzIwMTYwNCcKJzIwMDAwMScKJzAwMDExMicKJzEyMzQwNSc)

**Explanation**

```
            % Implicitly grab input as a string
'yyyymm'    % Push the format string as a string literal
2$YO        % Convert to a serial date number
12          % Number literal, pre-defined datestring of 'mmmyy'
XO          % Convert from serial date number to string using this format
Xk          % Convert to uppercase
            % Implicitly display
```

Comment: I don't see how this can be beaten so.. gg

Answer (score 26):

## Python 3, 70 bytes

```
from time import*
lambda s:strftime("%b%y",strptime(s,"%Y%m")).upper()
```

This uses the built-in `strftime` and `strptime` functions.

For 1 byte more, here's a version which parses the string manually:

```
lambda s:" JFMAMJJASONDAEAPAUUUECOENBRRYNLGPTVC"[int(s[4:])::12]+s[2:4]
```

This encodes the month names in an interesting way (thanks to Henry Gomersall for saving a byte).

Comment: That manual parsing is crazy.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I got the idea from [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/407/45162).

Comment: Ugh I was going to do exactly your 72 byte answer +1

Comment: Your manual version can be done in 69 bytes in Python 2 if you take a number as input: ``lambda n:"JFMAMJJASONDAEAPAUUUECOENBRRYNLGPTVC"[n%100-1::12]+`n`[2:4]``.

Comment: @xnor Would that work for the `000112` example?

Comment: @Neil Oh, it wouldn't work there.

Comment: Though this loses a byte: `lambda s:" JFMAMJJASONDAEAPAUUUECOENBRRYNLGPTVC"[int(s[4:])::12]+s[2:4]`

Comment: Why not simply `import time`?

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae - "import time" would save you 6 characters, but would cost you 10 ("time.", twice)

Answer (score 19):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>49</s> <s>46</s> 40 bytes

```powershell
date "$args".insert(4,'-')-U %b%y|% *per
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PyWxJFVBSSWxKL1YSS8zrzi1qETDREddV11TN1RBNUm1skZVQasgtej////qRgaGZgYm6gA)

*Thanks to @Joey for saving 3 bytes!*

Takes input `$args` as an explicit string (e.g., `'201604'`) via command-line input. Uses the `string.Insert()` function to put a `-` in the appropriate space, and that resultant string forms input to the [`Get-Date` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) with the `-U`format parameter specifying the three-month shorthand plus two-digit year. We then tack on a `.ToUpper()` to make the output string capitalized. That string is left on the pipeline and printing is implicit.

Also, as pointed out, this is locale-sensitive. Here's the locale information that I'm using where this works correctly.

```powershell
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> get-culture

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1033             en-US            English (United States)
```

Comment: You don't need to quote the `MMMyy`, since it's a simple argument to a cmdlet. You also could just use `-UFormat %b%y`, i.e. `-u %b%y` instead, which is even shorter. Side note: This solution is locale-sensitive (which I personally dislike), but would be a fair bit longer to account for that, admittedly.

Comment: Excellent call with the `-UFormat` instead. Thanks! I also did not know about the quotes around `MMMyy` - that's good to know for the future.

Answer (score 17):

## Bash + coreutils, 18

Requires 64-bit version of `date` for the given testcases, [which recognises dates earlier than 14th December 1901](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7688/date-years-prior-to-1901-are-treated-as-invalid).

```
date -d$101 +%^b%y
```

Answer (score 10):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>71</s> 70 bytes

*Thanks to Sp3000 for saving 1 byte.*

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding. The trailing linefeed is significant.

```
(..)(..)$
DECNOVOCTSEPAUGJULJUNMAYAPRMARFEBJANXXX$2$*¶$1
+`...¶

R-6`.
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAooLi4pKC4uKSQKREVDTk9WT0NUU0VQQVVHSlVMSlVOTUFZQVBSTUFSRkVCSkFOWFhYJDIkKsK2JDEKK2AuLi7CtgoKUi02YC4&input=MjAxNjA0CjIwMDAwMQowMDAxMTIKMTIzNDA1)

#### Explanation

Taking `201604` as an example:

```
(..)(..)$
DECNOVOCTSEPAUGJULJUNMAYAPRMARFEBJANXXX$2$*¶$1
```

This swaps the last two digits of the year with the month while also expanding the month in unary using linefeeds, and prepending the list of months in reverse so we'd get:

```
20DECNOVOCTSEPAUGJULJUNMAYAPRMARFEBJANXXX¶¶¶¶16
```

Where the `¶` represent linefeeds (0x0A).

```
+`...¶
```

Now we repeatedly remove three non-linefeed characters followed by a linefeed. That is we eat up the list of months from the end for each linefeed representing a month:

```
20DECNOVOCTSEPAUGJULJUNMAYAPRMARFEBJANXXX¶¶¶¶16
20DECNOVOCTSEPAUGJULJUNMAYAPRMARFEBJAN¶¶¶16
20DECNOVOCTSEPAUGJULJUNMAYAPRMARFEB¶¶16
20DECNOVOCTSEPAUGJULJUNMAYAPRMAR¶16
20DECNOVOCTSEPAUGJULJUNMAYAPR16
```

This is why we've inserted that `XXX`: since the months start counting from `1`, we'll always remove at least three characters, even for January.

```
R-6`.
```

Finally, we remove everything up to the 6th character from the end. In other words we only keep the last five characters.

Comment: That's pretty dang clever.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>50</s> 46 bytes

```
q2/1>~i("4H~0ë~³!ò²×¶7Ö"256b25b'Af+3/=\
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q2%2F1%3E~i%28%224H~0%C3%AB%C2%99~%C2%B3%C2%90!%C3%B2%C2%B2%C3%97%C2%8C%C2%9D%C2%B6%C2%90%1F%1F7%C3%96%22256b25b'Af%2B3%2F%3D%5C&input=201604) Thanks to Martin Ender for compressing the string to save a few bytes.

#### Explanation

```
q2/  e# Get input and divide it into groups of 2, like ["20" "16" "04"]
1>~  e# Discard the first item and dump the remaining array to the stack
i(   e# Convert the top value (month) to an integer and decrement it, because
     e# arrays are zero-indexed
"..."256b25b e# Convert this string from base-256 to base-25
'Af+ e# "Add" a capital A to each number to get the letters
3/   e# Divide into groups of 3 to make an array of month names
=\   e# Get the requested month and swap the elements to put the year on
     e# top, so it is printed last
```

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB / Octave, 42 bytes

```
@(x)upper(datestr(datenum(x,'yyyymm'),12))
```

Creates an anonymous function named `ans` that is called with a string representing the date: `ans('201604')`.

[**Online Demo**](http://ideone.com/a2ND79)

This solution uses `datenum` to convert the input date to a serial date number, and then `datestr` with the predefined output spec of `mmmyy` (`12`) to yield the string representation in the required format. Finally, we use `upper` to change it to `MMMYY` since the uppercase month is not an output option.

Comment: Wow, gj on beating everyone else in a non-golfing language!

Answer (score 6):

### Bash, <s>39</s> 28 bytes

```
date -d$101 +%b%y|tr a-z A-Z
```

Thanks [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)!

Answer (score 6):

## Java 7, 137 characters (161 bytes)

```
String d(String i){return Integer.toString("憯䷳烣㘿烪摿摽㛨近筍矯䏔".charAt(Integer.parseInt(i.substring(4))-1),36).toUpperCase()+i.substring(2,4);}
```

Consider each month name (JAN, FEB etc...) is a number in base 36 and encode it into corresponding Unicode symbol. Then get corresponding symbol from the string encode it back again in base 36 and after that some plain string manipulations.

Slightly ungolfed:

```
String d(String input){
return 
  Integer.toString("憯䷳烣㘿烪摿摽㛨近筍矯䏔" // encoded month names
  .charAt(Integer.parseInt(input.substring(4))-1),36) // get a symbol from encoded names at position input[4:], decode it to base 36 value
  .toUpperCase()+input.substring(2,4); // get it to upper case and add year
}
```

You can see it running here: https://ideone.com/IKlnPY

Answer (score 5):

### 05AB1E, <s>51</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
2ô¦`ï<•r–ºþ¯Bê€õaPù£—^5AºüLwÇ–è•35B3ôsèsJ
```

**Explanation**

```
                                           # implicit input, 123405
2ô                                         # split input into pieces of 2, ['12','34','05']
  ¦`                                       # push last 2 elements to stack, '05', '34'
    ï<                                     # convert month to its int index, 4
      •r–ºþ¯Bê€õaPù£—^5AºüLwÇ–è•35B        # get compressed string containing 3-letter months, 
                                             JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC
                                   3ô      # split into pieces of 3
                                             ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
                                     sè    # get month at index retrieved earlier, MAY
                                       sJ  # join with 2-digit year and implicitly print, MAY34
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MsO0wqTDrzzigKJy4oCTwrrDvsKvQsOq4oKsw7VhUMO5wqPigJReNUHCusO8THfDh-KAk8Oo4oCiMzVCM8O0c8OoczHDqEo&input=MTIzNDA1)

9 bytes saved thanks to string compression, courtesy of @Adnan

Comment: `•r–ºþ¯Bê€õaPù£—^5AºüLwÇ–è•35B` instead of `"JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"` saves 9 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>87</s> <s>84</s> <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```
x=>(new Date(x.replace(/.{4}/,'$&-'))+'').slice(4,7).toUpperCase()+x.slice(2,4)
```

To get the month, gets the date (which is formed of "YYYYMM" converted to "YYYY-MM") and retrieves the characters 5 to 8, that are exactly the first three letters of the month. But it costs much to convert it to upper case.

Demo:

```js
function s(x) {
  return (new Date(x.replace(/.{4}/, '$&-')) + '').slice(4,7)
         .toUpperCase() + x.slice(2, 4)
}

console.log(s('201604'));
console.log(s('200001'));
console.log(s('000112'));
console.log(s('123405'));
```

Comment: First should be `APR16`

Comment: @Upgoat And what's appearing for you?

Comment: I'm getting `MAR16`

Comment: @Upgoat Huh, that's weird, why could it be this way? Because I [get this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/31ozm.png).

Comment: For me it does show `APR16`, but the third test case shows only `DEC` for me.

Comment: That's really strange, could you share the whole Date object you get? So as I could see what's happening.

Comment: OK in FF, Bad in Edge and Chrome for me.

Comment: Check the recent edit. @Enigna, what do you get?

Comment: Now they're all OK.

Comment: @Adnan Check the edit, please - should be fine now. Can't figure that oddness with March though.

Comment: Yes, it works now :).

Comment: @Upgoat What browser were you using?

Comment: @Emigna Does it work in all the browsers you've mentioned? (sorry for misspelling you the first time!)

Comment: Yes, it works in the 3 browsers I mentioned.

Comment: Could you, um, replace `x.replace(/.{4}/,'$&-')` with `x.replace(/..$/,'-$&')`?

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>77</s> 66 bytes

Saved 11 bytes thanks to @Bálint!

```
a=>(new Date(0,a[4]+a[5]-1)+"").slice(4,7).toUpperCase()+a[2]+a[3]
```

Get's the date by extracting the string returned by the `Date` class. then capitalizes and adds the year.

ES5 version:

```js
var a = prompt("Enter YYYYMM: ");
result = (new Date(0,a[4]+a[5]-1)+"").slice(4,7).toUpperCase()+a[2]+a[3]
alert(result);
```

Comment: I made one in 66 bytes with the same atob technique, but I can't copy it out

Comment: @Bálint I thought I got 66 bytes too but turns our byte counter was wrong due to to bad copy pasting ;)

Comment: You could get the month's name with `(Date(0,a[4]- -a[5])+"").substr(4,3)`

Comment: Or `(new Date(0,a[4]- -a[5])+"").substr(4,3)`

Comment: @Bálint oh wow, thanks! That's short!

Comment: I don't get that `a[4]- -a[5]`. What was wrong with `a[4]+a[5]-1`?

Comment: You can cut one more character by turning `(new Date(0,a[4]- -a[5])+"")` to `(new Date(0,a[4]- -a[5])+1)`

Comment: Also - just doing `new Date(a[4]+a[5])` generates valid month (at least in Chrome)

Comment: Wrong for me 201604 -> MAY16

Comment: @edc65 Whoops should be fixed now

Comment: @Guedes yeah >_> the months were one off fixed in same number of bytes by just subtracting one

Comment: Nice work. My first impulse was to do it all with strings, but the shortest I could make it was still 76 bytes: `d=>'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'.substr(d.slice(4)*3-3,3)+d[2]+d[3]`

Comment: `new Date(0,a[4]+a[5]-1)+""` => `new Date(0,a[4]+a[5]-1)+0`

Comment: `a[4]+a[5]-1` => `a%100-1`

Answer (score 5):

### Python, 83 bytes

```
from datetime import*
lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m').strftime('%b%y').upper()
```

Comment: I just posted an answer nearly identical to yours. I didn't see yours because it took a while to write the answer. If you want me to delete mine, I will, or you can use mine to get some extra bytes off.

Comment: That's fine, you beat me by 13 bytes, I'll concede. I like your manual answer, too.

Answer (score 5):

### Kotlin, 100 bytes

```
fun f(d:String)=SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").format(SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").parse(d)).toUpperCase()
```

Pretty straight forward use of Java SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Hmm, I don't know Kotlin, but since it's derived from Java, shouldn't you include the import of the `SimpleDateFormat` (i.e. `import java.text.*;`)?

Comment: Since the challenge asks for output, I would assume a print is required as part of your function.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>57</s> <s>56</s> 53 bytes

```
s->uppercase(Dates.format(DateTime(s,"yyyym"),"uyy"))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and returns a string. To call it, assign it to a variable.

First we construct a `DateTime` object using the type constructor and a format string. Note that the single `m` in the format string will get both one- and two-digit months, though the former case is irrelevant here. Since no days are specified, the first of the month is assumed.

We can then format the value as a string using the `Dates.format` function from the `Base.Dates` submodule. The string `uyy` gets the three-letter month name and two-digit year, but the result is in title case, e.g. Apr16 instead of the desired APR16, so we need to `uppercase` it.

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=Zj1zLT51cHBlcmNhc2UoRGF0ZXMuZm9ybWF0KERhdGVUaW1lKHMsInl5eXltIiksInV5eSIpKQoKZm9yIHRlc3QgaW4gWygiMjAxNjA0IiwiQVBSMTYiKSwgKCIyMDAwMDEiLCJKQU4wMCIpLCAoIjAwMDExMiIsIkRFQzAxIiksICgiMTIzNDA1IiwiTUFZMzQiKV0KICAgIHByaW50bG4oZih0ZXN0WzFdKSA9PSB0ZXN0WzJdKQplbmQ&input=) (includes all test cases)

Answer (score 4):

### C, <s>147</s> <s>145</s> 112 bytes

```c
main(m){char a[99]="JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC";scanf("%4s%d",a+50,&m);printf("%.3s%s",a+--m*3,a+52);}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/T0JSWL)

Thanks [ugoren](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3544/ugoren)!

Comment: Some cheap tricks - delete the `#include`, define `m` as a parameter - `main(m)`,

Comment: Also, the `%.3s` format saves the null termination.

Comment: Thanks @ugoren! I also changed `"%4s%2d"` to `"%4s%d"`.

Comment: `main(m){char a[9];scanf("%4s%d",a,&m);printf("%.3s%s","JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"+--m*3,a+2);}` lot shorter

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
ÐUr$/..../$,"$&-")+P s4,7 u +Us2,4
```

[Link.](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=0FVyJC8uLi4uLyQsIiQmLSIpK1AgczQsNyB1ICtVczIsNA==&input=IjIwMTUwNCI=)

Uses the same technique as my [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83597).

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>154</s> 113 bytes

```java
import java.text.*;s->new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").parse(s)).toUpperCase()
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZAxT8MwEIX3/opTJnuolYTCEsFCYXOXigkxHK5L3Sa2ZV9boiq/PTgk6oREbzjdkz7p3Xt7POF8vzn0qsYYQaKxlxmAsaTDFpWG1SAB1hSM/QLFpiNyoF1w5wgv30p7Ms5WCexmaUVCMgpWYOER@jh/svoMa9P4Wi@R9KsLDRLLpJRtm3GxHfXfUJtGykR5DFGzyLkg9@a9Ds@YNO@rwdEfP@vkOBmfnNlAk5JMz75/APIxBoV2PFKiNpJuhDuS8Imi2jIrFMvKvHjIFxnn1b9gmuIGcMCK8gawKO8W@f0V7BSS2rFrwaD5pfstuet/AA)

```java
import java.text.*;                 // Required import for SimpleDateFormat
s->                                 // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy")     //  Create a formatter with format "MMMyy"
   .format(                         //  Format the following:
     new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM") //   Create another formatter with format "yyyyMM"
     .parse(s))                     //   Parse the input with this format
  .toUpperCase()                    //  Convert everything to Uppercase and return
```

Comment: I think you can shorten it if you remove the import and instead directly refer to it with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @Frozn Actually, `import java.text.*;` is 19 bytes, and two times `java.text.` in front of both `SimpleDateFormat` is 20 bytes. So it would increase by 1 byte instead of lowering it.

Comment: Oh yea you're right. I always look at the ungolfed version and think that it's equal to the golfed one. Sorry :)

Comment: @Frozn Ah, also a bit my bad. Usually I still use `.*;` for the ungolfed code, but this time I seem to have neglected it. I have save options that automatically converts it to pure imports since I use Java in my job, and I simply forgot to change it to `import java.text.*;`..

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>94</s> 87 bytes

```
string C(string s)=>System.DateTime.Parse(s.Insert(4,"-")).ToString("MMMyy").ToUpper();
```

Saved 7 bytes by using C#6 Syntax.

[Try Online](http://csharppad.com/gist/1bf6575ea6e22e58e3bdcc79e205d905)

Comment: You can leave off return type information for lambdas, i.e `C(string s)=>...`

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 45 bytes

```
+:."AYw2ûDÈëKH§È¼DYÉx\E±oË"J*3sgz5+3J:z2 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUQAu/9weXRo//8rOi4iQVkMdzLDu0TDiMOrS0jCp8OIwrwCRFnDiXhcRcKxb8OLHCJKKjNzZ3o1KzNKOnoyIDT//zIwMTgwNA)

Explanation:

```
+:."AYw2ûDÈëKH§È¼DYÉx\E±oË"J*3sgz5+3J:z2 4
                                z           Take the input
                               g 5          Slice inclusively from index 5 to the end
                              s             Parse as an int
                            *3              Multiply by 3
                           J                Store in variable J, this also returns J
 :                                          Take a slice
  ."AYw2ûDÈëKH§È¼DYÉx\E±oË"                 Of this packed string
                           J*3sgz5          From the J we defined before
                                  +3J       To J+3
+                                           To this string, append
                                     :z     A slice of the index
                                       2 4  From [2,4).
```

The packed string contains `"JANJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"`. The two `JAN`s are so that I can index it pseudo-one-indexed.

EDIT: Fixed bug that was messing with TIO

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL, 49 Bytes

```
select to_char(to_date(n,'yyyymm'),'MONyy')from t
```

The data must be inserted in a table called `T` with a column `N` of type `VARCHAR2(6)`, `CHAR(6)` or , only if all the years are > 1000,  `NUMBER`

Usage:

```
drop table t;
create table t (n VARCHAR2(6));
insert into t values ('201604');
insert into t values ('200001');
insert into t values ('000112');
insert into t values ('123405');    

select to_char(to_date(n,'yyyymm'),'MONyy')from t;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use PRINT instead of SELECT and not refer to the table using a variable as input instead ? Declaring input variable and assigning the value does not affect the byte count

Comment: Is it allowed to take input from a table? The [codegolf tag info](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) suggests that no.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk the shortest way using print is 58 chars: `begin:n:=to_char(to_date(:n,'yyyymm'),'monyy');end;print n` and you need 42 extra chars for a single input(`VARIABLE n varchar2;BEGIN:n:='201605';END;`) instead of 31 (`insert into t values('000112');`) if you have shorter ways please tell me.

Comment: @pajonk in [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82773/weapons-of-math-instruction/82786#82786) nobody tell me anything about the use of tables

Comment: @pajonk according to [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341), you can use tables for input

Comment: Ok, just wanted to know. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

## Microsoft SQL Server, 57 Bytes

```
SELECT UPPER(FORMAT(CAST('201601'+'01' AS DATE),'MMMyy'))
```

The `Upper` function is required as format does not produce Upper case months as would be expected with the *MMM* format pattern.

**Usage:**

```
drop table t;
create table t (n VARCHAR(6));
insert into t values ('201604');
insert into t values ('200001');
insert into t values ('000112');
insert into t values ('123405');    

SELECT UPPER(FORMAT(CAST(n+'01' AS DATE),'MMMyy')) FROM t
```

Comment: Just saw your answer, it is alot like mine, didn't notice it until now, removed my answer

Comment: Is it allowed to take input from a table? The [codegolf tag info](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) suggests that no.

Comment: @pajonk the answer here doesn't use input from a table, the answer is the top line and the input variable is hardcoded. Note that you can use tables as input variables as i mention earlier. The bottom part is an example how to convert several values. TSQL doesn't have STDIN nor input statements. Only way of adding data is using variables or tables. All of my answers are using those for input

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

## Microsoft Excel VBA, 47 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
?UCase(MonthName([Right(A1,2)],1))[Mid(A1,3,2)]
```

Current version thanks to [@Engineer Toast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38183/engineer-toast), for pointing out the abbreviate option of the `MonthName` function.

#### Previous Version

```vb
?UCase(Format(DateSerial([Left(A1,4)],[Right(A1,2)],1),"MMMYY"))
```

Comment: Worth noting that Excel needs to be set to English, otherwise it returns locale-specific month name.

Comment: 48 bytes: `?UCase(MonthName(Right([A1],2),1))&Mid([A1],3,2)`

Comment: Turns out the Excel formula can be 46 bytes: `=UPPER(TEXT(RIGHT(A1,2)*28,"MMM"))&MID(A1,3,2)`

Answer (score 2):

## MediaWiki Template (with ParserFunctions), 29 bytes

```
{{uc:{{#time:My|{{{1}}}01}}}}
```

Only works if English locale is chosen.

[Try Sandbox](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Project:Sandbox&action=edit)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 65 bytes

```r
function(A)paste0(toupper(month.abb[el(A:1)%%100]),substr(A,3,4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchBC8IgFADge78iFoMnSLyntkPQQapLUES3iA5zbBSUk6m/32b4Hb8pDbs0RNuF92hBM9f60COEMTrXT/AdbXitW2Me/Qf0llhdE@KTcR@NDxNoLrliLA1QCaQGVcVWy5m@3qhZ/HdGZU/6gpg3H4myh@MeKS8JqXBT9qzvUqUf)

Takes input as a string, leverages the constant `month.abb`. Uses modulus and `substr` to extract relevant values.

Comment: clever use of `:` to convert to `integer`!

Comment: @Giuseppe Not my idea :) I took it from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12837/80010). I can probably apply it to a number of my existing answers!

Comment: @Giuseppe I just found a shorter hack using `el` - 1 less byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 75 bytes

```perl
$_=(1,JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC)[/..$/g].substr$`,2,2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbDUMfL0U/HzdVJx9cxSMcxIAhIR@p4hfoBsY@OY6i7TrBrgI6/c4iOn3@Yjours2a0vp6ein56rF5xaVJxSZFKgo6RjtH//4bGBhYGlv/yC0oy8/OK/@sWAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÐUò4)Åu ¸o¤Åë
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=0FXyNCnFdSC4b6TF6w&input=IjIwMTYwNCI)

```
ÐUò4)Åu ¸o¤Åë     :Implicit input of string U          > "201604"
Ð                 :Create Date object from
 Uò4              :  Partitions of U of length 4       > ["2016","04"]
    )             :End Date
     Å            :To date string                      > "Fri Apr 01 2016"
      u           :Uppercase                           > "FRI APR 01 2016"
        ¸         :Split on spaces                     > ["FRI","APR","01","2016"]
         o        :Modify the last element
          ¤       :  Slice off the first 2 characters  > ["FRI","APR","01","16"]
           Å      :Slice off the first element         > ["APR","01","16"]]
            ë     :Get every second element            > ["APR","16"]
                  :Implicitly join and output          > "APR16"
```

Comment: [Flagless 14 bytes: `ÐUò4)Å¸ó Ìo¤¬u`](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0FXyNCnFuPMgzG%2bkrHU&input=IjIwMTYwNCIgLVE)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 78 bytes

```javascript
i=>'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'.match(/.../g)[i[4]+i[5]-1]+i[2]+i[3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxP9PWTt3L0c/N1cnXMcgxIMjXMdIr1M8r1Mcx1D3YNcDfOcTPP8zF1VldLzexJDlDQ19PT08/XTM6M9okVjsz2jRW1xBEG4EI49j/mhrqRgZGhgbm6pqa1v8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Headascii](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Headascii), 331 bytes

```
UUU^U[UOUODOD]ONE.++++[]]]][]]]]+O[---[]]]][]]]][U]^U]OUOUOD++E.+++^^^U[U-()D]^P(]PD++++P:-()+++++]P-P---P:-()D+++]^P(]PD+++++P:-()]PD++++++]P++P:-()D^^^+++]P(]PD---]P:-()D^^]PD^++]PD-----]P:-()D^^]PD++]P(++^^^^^D+]P:-()]PD^^D++]P(++++++]P:D^^D^]P(++++]PD---]P;UPUP!.++^^^^^U[U)D^^++++]P(++]PD-]P:R-)D^^+++]P+PD+]P:+++]P+P--P;UPUP!
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23) Code will need to be pasted in and executed like this:

```js
erun("UUU^U[UOUODOD]ONE.++++[]]]][]]]]+O[---[]]]][]]]][U]^U]OUOUOD++E.+++^^^U[U-()D]^P(]PD++++P:-()+++++]P-P---P:-()D+++]^P(]PD+++++P:-()]PD++++++]P++P:-()D^^^+++]P(]PD---]P:-()D^^]PD^++]PD-----]P:-()D^^]PD++]P(++^^^^^D+]P:-()]PD^^D++]P(++++++]P:D^^D^]P(++++]PD---]P;UPUP!.++^^^^^U[U)D^^++++]P(++]PD-]P:R-)D^^+++]P+PD+]P:+++]P+P--P;UPUP!","your input here")
```

Headass/ascii is not particularly good at strings.

```
UUU^U[UOUODOD]ONE. Block 0

UU                 Discard the first two chars of input lol
  U^U[             Hold onto the last two digits of the year
      UOUODOD]O    ready MMYY for the next code block
               NE  Go to block 1
                 . Block separator


++++[]]]][]]]]+O[---[]]]][]]]][U]^U]OUOUOD++E. Block 1

++++[]]]][]]]]+O                               Save 65 for later ease of access
                [---[]]]][]]]][                -48
                               U]^             Add to first month digit and hold
                                  U]O          Add to second month digit and save
                                     UOUO      Save year digits
                                         D++E  Go to either block 1 or block 2,
                                                depending on whether the first
                                                digit of the month was 0 or 1
                                             . Block separator


+++^^^U[U-()...;UPUP!.      Block 2 (JAN-SEP)

+++^^^                      Store 9 on the accumulator
      U[                    Restore 65 from earlier
        U-()                If the second digit of the month is 1,
D]^P(]PD++++P                 Concatenate "JAN" to the string register
             :-()           Else if it's 2
+++++]P-P---P                 Concatenate "FEB" to the string register
             :-()           Else if it's 3
D+++]^P(]PD+++++P             Concatenate "MAR" to the string register
                 :-()       Else if it's 4
]PD++++++]P++P                Concatenate "APR" to the string register
              :-()          Else if it's 5
D^^^+++]P(]PD---]P            Concatenate "MAY" to the string register
                  :-()      Else if it's 6
D^^]PD^++]PD-----]P           Concatenate "JUN" to the string register
                   :-()     Else if it's 7
D^^]PD++]P(++^^^^^D+]P        Concatenate "JUL" to the string register
                      :-()  Else if it's 8
]PD^^D++]P(++++++]P           Concatenate "AUG" to the string register
                   :        Else
D^^D^]P(++++]PD---]P          Concatenate "SEP" to the string register
               ;UPUP!       Then concatenate the year digits from earlier and print!
                     .      Block separator, end of execution


++^^^^^U[U)D^...;UPUP!  Block 3 (OCT-DEC)

++^^^^^                 Store 10 on the accumulator 
       U[               Restore 65 from earlier
         U)             If the second digit of the month is 0,
D^^++++]P(++]PD-]P        Concatenate "OCT" to the string register
                  :R-)  Else if it's 1
D^^+++]P+PD+]P            Concatenate "NOV" to the string register
              :         Else
+++]P+P--P                Concatenate "DEC" to the string register
          ;UPUP!        Then concatenate the year digits from earlier and print!
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, 64 bytes

```
00000000: fcad ad50 ad2d 3030 86e0 d50a be19 0103  ...P.-00........
00000010: f003 f003 f02e a52e a458 abc3 4a41 4e46  .........X..JANF
00000020: 4542 4d41 5241 5052 4d41 594a 554e 4a55  EBMARAPRMAYJUNJU
00000030: 4c41 5547 5345 504f 4354 4e4f 5644 4543  LAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC
```

Callable function, input at `DS:SI`, output buffer at `ES:DI`.

Listing:

```
FC          CLD                         ; string direction forward 
AD          LODSW                       ; skip first two chars 
AD          LODSW                       ; load YY string 
50          PUSH AX                     ; save YY string 
AD          LODSW                       ; load month string 
2D 3030     SUB  AX, '00'               ; ASCII convert month 
86 E0       XCHG AH, AL                 ; endian convert 
D5 0A       AAD                         ; word convert to index (1-12) 
BE 0116     MOV  SI, OFFSET MTBL[-3]    ; month table (1-indexed) 
03 F0       ADD  SI, AX                 ; add month offset * 3 chars 
03 F0       ADD  SI, AX 
03 F0       ADD  SI, AX
2E A5   CS: MOVSW                       ; copy first two bytes of month
2E A4   CS: MOVSB                       ; copy third byte of month to output
58          POP  AX                     ; restore YY string 
AB          STOSW                       ; write YY to output 
C3          RET 
        MTBL: 
4A 41 4E    DB  'JAN' 
46 45 42    DB  'FEB' 
4D 41 52    DB  'MAR' 
41 50 52    DB  'APR' 
4D 41 59    DB  'MAY' 
4A 55 4E    DB  'JUN' 
4A 55 4C    DB  'JUL' 
41 55 47    DB  'AUG' 
53 45 50    DB  'SEP' 
4F 43 54    DB  'OCT'
4E 4F 56    DB  'NOV' 
44 45 43    DB  'DEC'
```

Sample runs:

[image]

Comment: Make it 62, as I guess you may want to add a CLD in front - otherwise direction is undefined.

Comment: In addition the code assumes that DS=CS which is only true in tiny model - which in turn doesn't need far input, does it? So to make it work the two MOVS* need a CS segment overwrite ... ending at 64 :))

Comment: @Raffzahn  just for that I'm not going to use MASM's long syntax for `MOVS` with segment override.

Comment: Fine with me - as long as the prefix gets generated.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 70 bytes

```
4(}.((,~(_3]\'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'){~1-~".)~2&}.){.)]
```

### Usage

```
   f =: 4(}.((,~(_3]\'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'){~1-~".)~2&}.){.)]
   f '201604'
APR16
   f '200001'
JAN00
   f '000112'
DEC01
   f '123405'
MAY34
```

### Explanation

```
4(}.((,~(_3]\'...'){~1-~".)~2&}.){.)] Input: s
                                    ] Identity function, gets the value s
4                                     The constant 4
                                 {.   Take the first 4 chars from s
                            2&}.      Drop the first 2 (Take the last 2) to get the year
  }.                                  Drop the first 4 chars from s to get the month
                        ".            Parse the month substring as a number
                     1-~              Subtract 1 from it
             '...'                    List of MMM month names
         _3]\                         Split the list into nonoverlapping sublists of size 3
      ,~                              Join the MMM month name with the year and return
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 39 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 2b 40 63 2e 22 41 59 12 56 0a 7c bd 93 e3 1c 07 +@c."AY.V.|.....
0000010: e3 d4 d9 ed 5b 49 02 cd b4 92 83 86 22 33 73 3e ....[I......"3s>
0000020: 32 7a 3a 7a 32 20 34                            2z:z2 4
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%40c.%22AY%12V%0A%7C%C2%BD%C2%93%C3%A3%1C%07%C3%A3%C3%94%C3%99%C3%AD%5BI%02%C3%8D%C2%B4%C2%92%C2%83%C2%86%223s%3E2z%3Az2+4&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=201604%0A200001%0A000112%0A123405&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 35 characters

(34 characters code + 1 character command-line option.)

(Just tried whether the `^` trick used by [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma) in his [Bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83611) works in jq too. Works. Now you know who inspired the most important character of this answer. (The alternative is to use the `ascii_upcase` function.))

```
strptime("%Y%m")|strftime("%^b%y")
```

Sample run (Option `-R` used only in this sample to pass all test cases.)

```
bash-4.3$ jq -Rr 'strptime("%Y%m")|strftime("%^b%y")' <<END
201604
200001
000112
123405
END
APR16
JAN00
DEC01
MAY34
```

On-line test: (Passing -R through URL is not supported – so input passed as JSON string literal. Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

- [200001](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=strptime(%22%25Y%25m%22)|strftime(%22%25%5Eb%25y%22)&j=%22200001%22)
- [000112](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=strptime(%22%25Y%25m%22)|strftime(%22%25%5Eb%25y%22)&j=%22000112%22)

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>154</s> <s>150</s> <s>114</s> 112 bytes

Takes six digit input into "b", separates the first four digits from the last two digits, abbreviates the 2-digit month and makes it uppercase, and concatenates it with the 3rd and 4th digit.

Golfed:

```
function(b){h=substr;i=sprintf;o="%06d";cat(toupper(month.abb[as.numeric(h(i(o,b),5,6))]),h(i(o,b),3,4),sep="")}
```

Ungolfed:

```
function(b){
   h=substr;i=sprintf;o="%06d";

   cat(
      toupper(month.abb[as.numeric(h(i(o,b),5,6))]),
      h(i(o,b),3,4),
   sep="")
}
```

EDITS: replaced duplicitous names with variables; fixed me being stupid. -2 bytes by turning function anonymous (thanks, cat).

Comment: Nice answer! You can leave off the `a=` for an anonymous function

Comment: @cat I'm not too familiar with anonymous functions but wouldn't I need to add parentheses at the beginning and end of the function if I removed the `a=` ? Something like this:
    `(function(m) {a=3;m*a})(10)`

Comment: Nope, `function(b){h=substr;i=sprintf;o="%06d";cat(toupper(month.abb[as.numeric(h(i(o,b),5,6))]),h(i(o,b),3,4),sep="")}` is a function object all on its own.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. on `RStudio with R 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)` I get `Error in i(o, b) : invalid format '%06d'; use format %s for character objects`

Comment: @cat Darn new versions messing everything up! I'm on RStudio running `R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)` and it works fine. How does this work here, should I get the new version and change up the code? Also thanks for the anonymous function tip!

Comment: @cat this also works on `R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)`

Comment: I've edited your post to include data about the version

Comment: @cat it works perfectly well on R 3.2.5. The call to the function (if saved as function `f`) should be `f(200612)`. The error you got implies you tried `f("200612")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 78 bytes

```php
<?=fscanf(STDIN,"%4d%d",$y,$m)?strtoupper(date("My",mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,$y))):0;
```

The ["year 2038 problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) may occur on some computers, as [here](http://ideone.com/Co4h4a). But not in others, as [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/671458cb2843390d9200c780021c361edcc6ce0e).

Comment: @Titus, please don't try to edit other peoples' posts if there are problems and insert your own solutions; instead, please comment on the answer OR create a new answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, <s>82</s> 78 bytes

```
[ [ 2 tail* 10 base> month-abbreviation ] [ 4 head 2 tail ] bi append >upper ]
```

Eshplained:

```
[                    ! new anonymouse function block (quotation)
  [                  ! new quotation 
    2 tail*          ! "201604" -> "04"
    10 base>         ! "04"     -> 4
    month-abbreviation ! 4 -> "Apr"
  ]                  ! end quotation
  [                  ! new quotation
    4 head           ! "201604" -> "2016"
    2 tail           ! "2016"   -> "16" 
  ]                  ! end quotation
  bi                 ! bifurcate two quotations to TOS
  append             ! "Apr" "16" -> "Apr16"
  >upper             ! "Apr16"    -> "APR16"
]                    ! end quotation
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 2.2, 149 bytes

```
let f = NSDateFormatter(),g = NSDateFormatter();f.dateFormat = "yyyyMM";g.dateFormat = "MMMyy"
g.stringFromDate(f.dateFromString(i)!).uppercaseString
```

Trying to get this shorter than Kotlin...  It's a shame `NSDateFormatter` doesn't have an initializer that sets its `dateFormat`.  `NSDateFormatter` also does not have a default `dateFormat` value, causing additional losses.

## Swift 3, 136 bytes

```
let f = DateFormatter(),g = DateFormatter();f.dateFormat = "yyyyMM";g.dateFormat = "MMMyy"
g.string(from: f.date(from: i)!).uppercased()
```

Thanks to the removal of the `NS` prefix on some classes, I was able to make the Swift 3 answer a little shorter.  Still not shorter than Kotlin though...

Test function and cases:

```
import Foundation
import XCTest

func dateConverter(i: String) -> String? {
    let f = DateFormatter(),g = DateFormatter();f.dateFormat = "yyyyMM";g.dateFormat = "MMMyy"

    if let date = f.date(from: i) {
        return g.string(from: date).uppercased()
    }

    return nil
}

XCTAssert(dateConverter(i: "201604") == "APR16")
XCTAssert(dateConverter(i: "200001") == "JAN00")
XCTAssert(dateConverter(i: "000112") == "DEC01")
XCTAssert(dateConverter(i: "123405") == "MAY34")
```

Comment: Don’t you have to `import Foundation` in Swift 3? I’ve never used Swift 3 seriously, but I know you need that in Swift 5 at least.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 85 bytes

```
DEF C D?MID$(@__JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC,VAL(D[4]+D[4])*3,3);D[2];D[3]END
```

`@__JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC` is equivalent to the string literal `"@__JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"`. `JAN` starts at index 3, so the program can calculate the position as `month*3` instead of `(month-1)*3` or `month*3-3`.

Answer (score 1):

## C# - 75 Bytes

```
s=>{return new System.DateTime(s/100,s%100,1).ToString("MMMyy").ToUpper();}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), <s>65</s> 59 bytes

**Solution:**

```
@[13 3#"DECJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOV";.*|x],*x:2 4_
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k)@[13 3#"DECJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOV";.*|x],*x:2 4_"201604"
"APR16"
q)k)@[13 3#"DECJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOV";.*|x],*x:2 4_"200001"
"JAN00"
q)k)@[13 3#"DECJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOV";.*|x],*x:2 4_"000112"
"DEC01"
q)k)@[13 3#"DECJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOV";.*|x],*x:2 4_"123405"
"MAY34"
```

**Explanation:**

Reshape the months of the year so that `0 => DEC` and `1 => JAN` ... `12 => DEC`.

```
@[13 3#"DECJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOV";.*|x],*x:2 4_ / the solution
                                                       2 4_ / cut input at indices 2 & 4, "201604" => ["16", "04"]
                                                     x:     / save as x
                                                    *       / take first
                                                   ,        / join with
@[                                           ;    ]         / apply @[list;index]
                                               *|x          / reverse (|), first (*) aka 'last'
                                              .             / value ("05" => 5)
       "DECJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOV"               / offset months of the year
  13 3#                                                     / reshape
```

**Bonus:**

**60 byte** version in [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok):

```
((13 3#"DECJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOV")@.*|x),*x:2 4_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0PD0FjBWFnJxdXZy9HPzdXJ1zHIMSDI1zHSK9TPK9THMdQ92DXA3znEzz9MSdNBT6umQlNHq8LKSMEkXsnIwNDMwETp/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Caché ObjectScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterSystems_Cach%C3%A9) - 65 bytes

**Golfed**

```
r i s d=$zcvt($zd($zdth(i_"01",8),6),"u") w $e(d,1,3)_$e(d,*-1,*)
```

**Ungolfed**

```
r i                            ; Read stdin and store into 'i'                      [200203]
   s d=                        ; Set the variable 'd' to the following...
       $zcvt(                  ; Convert the string
             $zd(              ; Parse the string as a caché date
                 $zdth(        ; Convert the date to horolog format (# days from 12/31/1840)
                       i_"01", ; Append the string "01" to variable 'i'             [20020301]
                       8       ; Use format #8 - "YYYYMMDD" (e.g. 20020301)
                      ),                                                            [58864,0]
                 6             ; Use format #6 - "Mmm [D]D YYYY" (e.g. Mar 1 2002)
                ),                                                                  [Mar 1 2002]
             "u"               ; Convert the string to uppercase
            )                                                                       [MAR 1 2002]
   w                           ; Write out the following...
     $e(d,1,3)                 ; Extract the substring from position 1 to 3 (inclusive) [MAR]
     _                         ; Concatenate
     $e(d,                     ; Extract the substring...
        *-1,                   ; ...from 1 character from the end of the string     [0]
        *                      ; ...to the last character                           [2]
       )                                                                            [02]
                                                                                    [MAR02]
```

**Commentary**

I don't think I've ever seen another Caché answer on this site. I'm only forced to know the language because of work (legacy code), but language itself is very powerful.

Some notes about the language:

- Caché doesn't really care about whitespace, so `r x r y` is the same as `r x` `\n` `r y`
- Each function is the shortname for the longer version:

  - `r` == `read`
  - `s` == `set`
  - `$zcvt` == `$zconvert`
  - `$zd` == `$zdate`
  - `$zdth` == `$zdateh`
  - `$e` == `$extract`
- Arrays are 1-indexed

Unfortunately, there is no online interpreter for Caché. Probably either because it's too obscure or maybe a licensing thing.

If you're interested in the language, you can check out their [docs](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS) on their very 90's looking website :)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 146 Bytes.

**Manipulating string**

**Code** [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUUjSrU5Mz8hWKS4pKijRySooyczWKS5OAXKCcjq6Rpo66gbqmTmJRUWJlfHJ@blJmXqpGUWJeeqqGoY4hUBqoMr64ICezRMPL0c/N1cnXMcgxIMjXMdIr1M8r1Mcx1D3YNcDfOcTPP8zF1VnHWFNTUw9hgRHICuva/2A3KBkZGJoZmCjY2ikoWadpQHiaekoxeUrWXDAVQGCIUAHiwVRw/QcA)

```
function f($d){echo strtr(ltrim(substr($d,-2),'0'),array_combine(range(1,12),
str_split(JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC,3))).substr($d,2,-2);}
```

**Explanation**

```
function f($d){
                                #strtr allows u to set an array to replace the ocurrences
echo strtr(ltrim(substr($d,-2),'0'),        #Substring of the last two numbers of the input, 
                                           #removing leading zero
    array_combine(range(1,12),      
    str_split(JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC,3)))
                                           #create an array of ["1"=>JAN, "2"=>FEB...12=>DEC], 
                                           #split the string by 3 characters
    .substr($d,2,-2);
                                           #Concatenate the 2 middle characters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 61 bytes

@Downgoat seems not there so I repost to optimize

a=>(new Date(0,a%100-1)+0).slice(4,7).toUpperCase()+a[2]+a[3]

Answer (score 1):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 155 bytes

Longest answer here.

```c
main(i){char*k,s[6],*a="JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC";gets(s);strcpy(k,s+2);memset(k+2,0,2);i=atoi(s+4)*3;memset(a+i,0,i);strcat(k,a+i-3);puts(k);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBC4IwHMXvfYqoy6Yr0qQOy2CVBVImlUFEhzGH/jEt2jpE9NltEBEd3@@99xMdLUTdhkqc76lsjpRO4dLNx40f0lDKf6L0DarMsLrkUCHAT5Hzm1UQdRyciMX9VsiieTBZsQ2LNyt2CJMoTJYsWWyDeD3dRev9LJi2aCa1QgpT4xPXBzJ/28W0lKWSGhW2S3rEZPC5vgBStoet/rflNpgWPl9u1sSQTh/T6904C0xfde06Q89x3g)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: [136 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dhx4UQKsnMTUUVKS4pysxLB4r9z03MzNPI1KxOzkgs0srWKY42i7UuKC0p1gAqSU4s0chNzS1OLQHzCio1snXSU0FymtpGQKRjoGOkqWukA1Wj5OXo5@bq5OsY5BgQ5OsY6RXq5xXq4xjqHuwa4O8c4ucf5uLqrKSdWJKfqVGsbaKpZQw0IFNT11hT07r2/38jQ3MTQ0MA "C (tcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>107</s> 104 bytes

```c
main(){char s[7];gets(s+1);write(1,memcpy(s,"JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"+~-atoi(s+5)*3,3),5);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6OSOxSKE42jzWOj21pFijWNtQ07q8KLMkVcNQJzc1N7mgUqNYR8nL0c/N1cnXMcgxIMjXMdIr1M8r1Mcx1D3YNcDfOcTPP8zF1VlJu043sSQ/E2iGqaaWsY6xpo6ppnXt//9GhuYmhoYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 42 bytes

```
Ac2>Q2+@c12."AY4H~0ë™~³!ò²×Œ¶7Ö"tiHTG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9weXRo//9BYzI@UTIrQGMxMi4iQVk0SH4ww6vCmX7Cs8KQIcOywrLDl8KMwp3CtsKQHx83w5YidGlIVEf//yIxMjM0MDUi)

```
Ac2>Q2+@c12."AY4H~0ë™~³!ò²×Œ¶7Ö"tiHTG   // With Input '123405'

   >Q2                                       // Get input from index 2 (3405)
Ac2 ^                                        // Split it in two and assign to G and H (G='34', H='05'])
           ."AY4H~0ë™~³!ò²×Œ¶7Ö"             // Packed string representing: "JANFEBMAR..."
        c12."    JANFEBMAR...     "        // Chop it into 12 pieces (["JAN", "FEB", "MAR"...])
                                     tiHT    // Convert "05" to 5, subtract 1.
       @  ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR"...]   tiHT    // Get element at that index (MAY)
      +           "MAY"                  G   // "MAY" + 34
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), <s>69 55</s> 51 bytes

```
f={sprintf('%Tb',(it[4..5]as int)*22**7L)+it[2..3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDfa8IwEMff81fkRZI4F9JYuwdxIOoehh0y3ECGD7c2nR1tU9JMKOLf3qWlSMF7urvP/fje/Ritz3XTJItLVZq0sAklo/03mdDUfvmcz45QYZdmYynH46cte3B5yfn0eG2gqpSx2HVI4QXCJwwvFpgsd@9eQNCQOvN6@rp8E2JIW@bJnq43K1c5oJ6c@mLW03B5mPoEoTQvtcO/cAZu01zxrY4gW4NV83uWaJOD5S3du/ilC60yc0Q9d0cQMB7pLFORxZfbHK6TgwKzhppKIcUEp5Zd21EbiE74gmP8@Iyws5vS2/fa@pGQMZngmOe6sKdPyP4U606Iezn0To7buOucgpIwDOuaMMat/ihLZVZQKcrQtfkH)

This formats a millisecond value as an uppercase month name: `sprintf('%Tb',value)`.  The magic value of 22^7 is a value such that `n * 22^7` milliseconds after epoch is in the `nth` month of the year of 1970.  This value was derived by testing all possible 1 to 2 digit values.  Therefore `month * 22^7` will yield a value within that month.

1. 1970-01-29
2. 1970-02-27
3. 1970-03-28
4. 1970-04-26
5. 1970-05-25
6. 1970-06-23
7. 1970-07-22
8. 1970-08-19
9. 1970-09-17
10. 1970-10-16
11. 1970-11-14
12. 1970-12-13

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 85 bytes

```hs
f s=3`take`drop(read(drop 4s)*3-3)"JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"++[s!!2,s!!3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYbNCoJAGADvPcXn0kGzYH@sm4fNLJA0sQwiAhdWSfxlV@jxN53DzHyFbsq2NaYC7bNiEk1ZSDWMtiqFtJcDTzsbtmMOinhyDo8xz3iaxfwV5UmUX3l@uYfpLXgkt@cpDJDrvrVl0e0s9jGdqHvwQQ4rgFHV/QRr6MQI1dzfoKQGRDE5YA8oniGwiFAglHl4j8wf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `o`, 37 bytes

```
4ȯI«×g~Þ¯p-Ḃ:u‹Ẇ¹²Ṗ¨€r;↓§%«3ẇ$‹i⇧₴4Ẏ∷
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=o&code=4%C8%AFI%C2%AB%C3%97g%7E%C3%9E%C2%AFp-%E1%B8%82%3Au%E2%80%B9%E1%BA%86%C2%B9%C2%B2%E1%B9%96%C2%A8%E2%82%ACr%3B%E2%86%93%C2%A7%25%C2%AB3%E1%BA%87%24%E2%80%B9i%E2%87%A7%E2%82%B44%E1%BA%8E%E2%88%B7&inputs=%27202107%27&header=&footer=)

```
4ȯI                # Month as int
   «...«3ẇ         # Compressed string of month names
          $‹i      # Get the correct month
             ⇧₴    # Uppercase and print
               4Ẏ∷ # Get the last two digits of year
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua 5.3, 82 bytes

```
i=io.read()print(os.date("%b%y",os.time({year=i//100,month=i%100,day=1})):upper())
```

Needs to be run on an english machine, as the month name is language specific.

Version that works in any locale **91 bytes**

```
i=io.read()j=i%100*3 print(("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"):sub(j-2,j)..i:sub(3,4))
```

Comment: `%100` can be `%20`

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 85 bytes

```scala
s=>"JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC".drop(30*s(4)+3*s(5)-1587).take(3)+s(2)+s(3)
```

The index lookup `30*s(4)+3*s(5)-1587` is a golfed version (via ASCII arithmetics) of the more readable `s.slice(4,6).toInt*3-3`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9Ba4NAEIXv@RXD4mG3iWHX1bSUKtjUFqRrQqwFjzbRYitqXSmF4G83Y4TOYWb4ZuC9p49ZlY3Nx1d@7CHFUspSSqUp5H99Xp80@G0L5wXAb1ZBcQ9x35X1J7je/zZq1yOhHz0Hj8o/@PuD8tMwicLk1U9e4mC/275Fu/enYEvWp65pqeQ3mtpsKXE4zBTO3S1b99l3TiVbampNTbIRoGg6oLRcNQweTIjzH0osLjbcJmB6QFBJbMgKEGKJGaIPzic4IWHNELXxjlBY0ubODNGltAlj13AALYbpq5pqYpwLWrIBXBeM5mrCKAnDp2ExjBc)

I also tried the nice trick by @cliffroot to represent the names of the months via Chinese characters. This gives the following variant that is 23 characters shorter (62 instead of 85), but at the end 1 byte longer (86 instead of 85):

`s=>""+BigInt(""+"憯䷳烣㘿烪摿摽㛨近筍矯䏔"(10*s(4)+s(5)-528),36)+s(2)+s(3)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 56 bytes

```
[ 2 tail 2 cut dec> months "%b"strftime >upper prepend ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY0xD4IwFIR3f8WFxNUAooMmrMbFxTgRhmd5SCMtpX2Ewfjba73hvlxu@HpSMvn4uF9vlxMCzwtbxQGGZNg58oE93uwtj1A0su3Io598ukXbFygoraEnzCvOm828flDmxTGvElIK/KsoUZT7Kj/gGxuUENJjgloEHasaZrIyBGTbZxbE96INo16cS2rn2SUp2mjIoUlbW0ELJjXEHw)

### Explanation

```
          ! "201604"
2         ! "201604" 2
tail      ! "1604"
2         ! "1604" 2
cut       ! "16" "04"
dec>      ! "16" 4
months    ! "16" T{ duration f 0 4 0 0 0 0 }
"%b"      ! "16" T{ duration f 0 4 0 0 0 0 } "%b"
strftime  ! "16" "Apr"
>upper    ! "16" "APR"
prepend   ! "APR16"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 115 bytes

```python
m='JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC'.split();d=input();print("%s%s"%(m[int(d[4]+d[5])-1],d[2]+d[3]))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9dW3cvRT8HN1UnB1zFIwTEgCEhHKniF@gGxj4JjqLtCsGuAgr9ziIKff5iCi6uzul5xQU5miYamdYptZl5BKYhVUJSZV6KhpFqsWqykqpEbDeKlRJvEaqdEm8Zq6hrG6qREG4F4xrGamv//GxoZmxiYAgA)

Comment: I suggest that you look into lambda functions and generally try to avoid use of `split()` - That said, I think that [JQBLZ's manual string parsing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83603/61846) may already be optimal for Py3 - you should take a look at that one

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
²ẸN“¤ɼḋġŀ§P¡^Ȥḥ)ñt:²æṆµṖƒr“R³İs+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWN20PbXq4a4ffo4Y5h5ac3PNwR_eRhUcbDi0POLQw7sSShzuWah7eWGJ1aNPhZQ93th3a-nDntGOTioCKgw5tPrKhWHtJcVJyMdSoBSuUDI2MTQxMlSB8AA)

##### Explanation

```python
²ẸN“...“R³İs+    # Implicit input        ->  "123405"
²                # Split into pairs      ->  ["12","34","05"]
 Ẹ               # Dump onto stack       ->  "12", "34", "05"
  N              # Cast to integer       ->  "12", "34", 5
   “...“         # Compressed string     ->  "12", "34", 5, "janfeb...novdec"
        R        # Uppercase it          ->  "12", "34", 5, "JANFEB...NOVDEC"
         ³       # Split into threes     ->  "12", "34", 5, ["JAN",...,"DEC"]
          İ      # One-based indexing    ->  "12", "34", "MAY"
           s+    # Swap and concatenate  ->  "12", "MAY34"
                 # Implicit output       ->  "MAY34"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 107 bytes

```go
import(."time";."strings")
func f(s string)string{t,_:=Parse("200601",s)
return ToUpper(t.Format("Jan06"))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVDdSsMwFMYLb_IUh8Aggawk3SwyqTDUXQyU4s-F6NjCbEvYmpYk9WbsSbwZgi_hm-jT2DQuN-f7zs_3nZyPz7I-fDdyvZFlDpVUGiFVNbVxES4qh79aVwzPfzYhRyLsVJXjiwhbZ5QuLaaoaPUaCmIhpGgIO8eWkzSTxuYEx5wnXGBmKTK5a42Gx_qpaXJDXDSrTSUdwXOpeYIp3QfL35PTXtivRCjsUCOVsTBJYRVzkfAxdG-a3YsEdeqcC8_n0zvOkWci9vz65ooLJOLRmJ95fjt9Ho1XqKgNLNlW6dzrGam7rz80W-VIb8Lwq8beEgqVb99601mPiJ-hCJRmULfOF0LLC1-wIxQLBGUdikTprj3rDuIKggcWyMBSGF5CD99pZ8SOasxPBd009ZiiPfq_xuEQ4h8)

I wish Go's time formatting strings allowed all caps months like `JAN06`; that would save 22 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 148 bytes

```
@set d=%1
@for %%m in (JAN.01 FEB.02 MAR.03 APR.04 MAY.05 JUN.06 JUL.07 AUG.08 SEP.09 OCT.10 NOV.11 DEC.12)do @if %%~xm==.%d:~4% echo %%~nm%d:~2,2%
```

No date libraries to speak of so manual parsing ftw. I don't know whether the rules of Code Golf allow creating 12 appropriately-named files in the current directory, resulting in something like this:

```
@set d=%1
@for %%m in (*.%d:~4%)do @echo %%~nm%d:~2,2%
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 46 + 6 for `-rdate` = 52

For completeness, if nothing else.

```
->d{Date.strptime(d,'%Y%m').strftime('%^b%y')}
```

See the tests on repl.it: https://repl.it/Cj7z

Comment: The closest I could get without `rdate` was 70 bytes, so this looks like the winning tactic for Ruby.

Comment: [-6](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339)?

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 96 bytes

```tsql
declare @i varchar(8)
select  @i = '201604'
select upper(left(datename(month,@i+'01'),3)) + substring(@i,5,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 142 bytes

```
s->(new String[]{"JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"})[Integer.decode(s.substring(4))-1]+s.substring(2,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 103 bytes

```
[0n]sP[JAN][FEB][MAR][APR][MAY][JUN][JUL][AUG][SEP][OCT][NOV][DEC]Csi[lid1-si:mz1<M]dsMxA0~;mPA0~dZ2>Pp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc7BCoJAEAbgu0/hCwSzm0VYBJtaIKmLZVDDHML1IGgI60E69Orbrs7hn4/hP4yqDQe2g8AgfEhLTEVOeE5OhJkoCYUsnZ6EaZW7uNpbdSG8JZKwiO6EefEgjJOIIt1i1yq20m3Yf9khI6WzScBv30ub6sWPcjAMJI6NHv36rRsd0uAhg7nj1lKyHdKxZz/bQuAPXTxZ22GLnRhfzPg6gM1s8wc)

`[0n]sP` is a macro that just prints a 0 w/o a newline for the sake of padding 1-9.

`[JAN]`...`[DEC]` places the strings on the stack. `Csi[lid1-si:mz1<M]dsMx` is a macro that decrements `i` from 12, popping the strings off of the stack and placing them at index `i` in the array `m`. Stops when one item (input) is left on the stack.

`100~;mP` does quotient/remainder division by 100, and prints the value from `m` indexed by the remainder. The quotient is left on the stack. `100~dZ2>Pp` again gets the remainder after dividing by 100, runs the padding macro `P` this is one digit long, and then prints.

Without any way of manipulating strings, I don't think that part is golfable. Doing any sort of wizardry with JAN/JUN/JUL would likely take far more bytes than the strings themselves.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 98 bytes

```
proc C d {scan $d %2d%2d%2d d y m
format %s%02d [string tou [clock f [clock sc $m/1/0] -f %b]] $y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc5BDoMgEAXQvaf4C1k2ArW9gMegLCjEpqkIAVwY49npaNOfSeblb2aKnWqNKVgMcNiyNTNaBybdb6hc4ZsxJG8KWGacOpVLes8vlLBA2SnYD8Y/skXrO9FxjcsI9tQa7brXyZt4HGgkF3feg0KkiJMHhDwp5LXnt5M7triUTA89oAZaeq9f)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 115 bytes

```
proc C d {scan $d %2d%2d%2d d y m
format %s%02d [lindex {. JAN FEV MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC} $m] $y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BC4JAFITv/oo56DV2zbovmwVSKpZCmAdxCwJXRQ0S8bfb04Y3zMdc5vVFOc9NWxeQUBi7Iq9gKli2@h@VA7Txqlud97A6i1GXlu9KPb8YN/CEj6Ob4CIiiDCivMOLffIZIj7h6oYI5A1@kODgygmmzmAO01zqvFkWDZvxPXNAIiTxFRfg9orc3jpst@KEsfn0HX34QCopsmn@AQ)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 144 bytes

```
proc C d {scan $d %2d%2d%2d d y m
format %s%02d [string map {10 OCT 11 NOV 12 DEC 1 JAN 2 FEV 3 MAR 4 APR 5 MAY 6 JUN 7 JUL 8 AUG 9 SEP} $m] $y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5LC4JQEIX3/Ypvoft7b9pjKWZBlEUvCGshShFoidoixN9uYx2GmY@zmHPqJOu6onwl@KQ0VRI/sVJsk/5HzA/54PYq87jGrmwlXlTV5eN5J48LGq3Y@Ae0Jtyc0IZZ4KNZeiGGeXBiyNrb4eBtd7jCZ0YsjyFj2SsmeMcFU/bBtsXKr1iftsv6z1JnYJQeKQeRoEj/sAcJ6lGboaPcH7Y0xbuupP6FyJdzbbsv)

Comment: Failed outgolf: https://tio.run/##TY5NC4JAGITv/Yr3oJcg2F2t@7JZIPmBpRC2B1GTwNVlNUjE326rXRoG5pk5TZ/X8yxVmwODAsYuzxowCjBJ8bMeBxCbZ6tE1oPZmUhvaderV1OBypqqBJf6JyfxaETDyKN3N/bd@ELj89UJA3bzg@ToMEjLj1RgiK21s/h/w5yDMUxzLTK5PNgQhA/IBi2NWnjFBTBZERPLRvsVJxjlu@/04wekTAef5i8

Comment: Another fail: https://tio.run/##RY5NDoIwEIX3nOItYGloK3oBvEXpAosaI6VNWxaEcPY6/BhfJplvXiZvJuo@JeetRo0Oc9DtgLxDIbq9yJxgsqf1po0oQsHIkyH69/BCtKNzDw@pe6s/OJaOaY8yJS8ZCadfxE39@a4U8mlJvWndej4TjF9ZBRIhiW@4AhcbcnGu2GXDBbMbY6B3G8iamlrSFw

Comment: Yet another: https://tio.run/##NY7BCoMwEETv/Yo5mGMxSW1/wOJPpDnYaEupMSGJBxG/PV2VDgvz2IGdTWbI2QdnUKPDEk07oujAZHcMLWfYk4p9QoOXC7ZNGiwyTpmKKXzGN5KbvO8DlBmc@aJo/nScs6UoOQlnSthdH/7UGsW85sG2fqs@SS5uvAKJkCR23EDIHYW8VPy644rFTynSqw@omkyv@Qc

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 75 bytes

Here is my obvious Python lambda, takes and returns a string, hope I didn't miss some obvious hole:

```
lambda x:"JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"[3*int(x[4:])-3:][:3]+x[2:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 55 bytes

```php
<?=date(My,strtotime(wordwrap($argn,4,"-",1)))&"___??";
```

Run as pipe with `-n` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c16280314b3cdfee4c508662fe04e690083b440f). Requires PHP 5 or later.

Answer (score 0):

## Base R, 78 bytes

```
paste(casefold(month.abb,upper=T)[strtoi(substr(A,5,6))],substr(A,3,4),sep="")
```

Not sure if this is required to be formatted as a standalone function, but if so, it is 91 bytes:

```
function(A){paste(casefold(month.abb,upper=T)[strtoi(substr(A,5,6))],substr(A,3,4),sep="")}
```

Comment: You will need to use the function, your first piece of code is called a snippet, and they are disallowed.  I don't know much about R but you can also use a complete program or anonymous function if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm new to this game. Is there a general documentation for the rules of the game?

Comment: [Yes there is](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).  Note that these are just defaults so they can be overridden by individual challenges, however they rarely are.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 72 Bytes

```python
lambda x:'JFMAMJJASONDAEAPAUUUECOENBRRYNLGPTVC'[int(x[4:])-1::12]+x[2:4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSt3LzdfR18vLMdjfz8XR1THAMTQ01NXZ39XPKSgo0s/HPSAkzFk9OjOvRKMi2sQqVlPX0MrK0ChWuyLayMok9n9BEUgqTSMzr6C0RENTU/O/kYGhmYEZAA)

Uses a stepping approach.

Comment: See [jqkul's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83603/553720) for -1 byte.